# How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'group by' query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, string-aggregation

I am looking for a way to concatenate the strings of a field within a group by query. So for example, I have a table:

| ID | COMPANY_ID | EMPLOYEE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Anna |
| 2 | 1 | Bill |
| 3 | 2 | Carol |
| 4 | 2 | Dave |

and I wanted to group by company_id to get something like:

| COMPANY_ID | EMPLOYEE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Anna, Bill |
| 2 | Carol, Dave |

There is a built-in function in mySQL to do this [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Markus Döring's answer is technically better.

Comment: @pstanton, Döring's answer is only better for 8.4 and below.

Comment: This question appears to be better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This should be the valid answer now https://stackoverflow.com/a/47638417/243233

Answer (score 714, accepted):

#### PostgreSQL 9.0 or later:

Modern Postgres (since 2010) has the [`string_agg(expression, delimiter)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) function which will do exactly what the asker was looking for:

```
SELECT company_id, string_agg(employee, ', ')
FROM mytable
GROUP BY company_id;
```

Postgres 9 also added the ability to specify an `ORDER BY` clause [in any aggregate expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES); otherwise you have to order all your results or deal with an undefined order. So you can now write:

```
SELECT company_id, string_agg(employee, ', ' ORDER BY employee)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY company_id;
```

#### PostgreSQL 8.4.x:

Please note that [support for Postgres 8.4 ended in 2014](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/), so you should probably upgrade for more important reasons than string aggregation.

PostgreSQL 8.4 (in 2009) introduced [the aggregate function `array_agg(expression)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-aggregate.html) which collects the values in an array. Then `array_to_string()` can be used to give the desired result:

```
SELECT company_id, array_to_string(array_agg(employee), ', ')
FROM mytable
GROUP BY company_id;
```

#### PostgreSQL 8.3.x and older:

When this question was originally posed, there was no built-in aggregate function to concatenate strings. The simplest custom implementation ([suggested by Vajda Gabo in this mailing list post](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2003-09/msg00177.php), among many others) is to use the built-in `textcat` function:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE textcat_all(
  basetype    = text,
  sfunc       = textcat,
  stype       = text,
  initcond    = ''
);
```

[Here is the `CREATE AGGREGATE` documentation.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-createaggregate.html)

This simply glues all the strings together, with no separator. In order to get a ", " inserted in between them without having it at the end, you might want to make your own concatenation function and substitute it for the "textcat" above. Here is one I put together and tested on 8.3.12:

```
CREATE FUNCTION commacat(acc text, instr text) RETURNS text AS $$
  BEGIN
    IF acc IS NULL OR acc = '' THEN
      RETURN instr;
    ELSE
      RETURN acc || ', ' || instr;
    END IF;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This version will output a comma even if the value in the row is null or empty, so you get output like this:

```
a, b, c, , e, , g
```

If you would prefer to remove extra commas to output this:

```
a, b, c, e, g
```

Then add an `ELSIF` check to the function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION commacat_ignore_nulls(acc text, instr text) RETURNS text AS $$
  BEGIN
    IF acc IS NULL OR acc = '' THEN
      RETURN instr;
    ELSIF instr IS NULL OR instr = '' THEN
      RETURN acc;
    ELSE
      RETURN acc || ', ' || instr;
    END IF;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I had to S&R varchar to text (latest pgsql stable) but this is great!

Comment: You can write the function in SQL only, which is easier for installation (plpgsql has to be installed by the superuser). See my post for an example.

Comment: "There is no built-in aggregate function to concatenate strings" - why wouldn't you use `array_to_string(array_agg(employee), ',')`?

Comment: +1 for the PostgreSQL 9.0 function.  If you need to be concerned about pre-9.0, Markus's answer is better.

Comment: Note that recent versions of Postgres also allow an `Order By` clause inside the aggregate function, e.g. `string_agg(employee, ',' Order By employee)`

Comment: NB: You may need to convert field to text: string_agg(something_id::text, ', ')

Comment: IBM's Big SQL is sorta based on Postgres, and you can accomplish this with something similar to `array_agg` (which works, but `array_to_string` does not). Use `listagg` instead, like so: `listagg(DISTINCT employee, ', ')`.

Comment: @Neall I just realised I've heavily edited your answer because I thought it was mine! Oops. I hope you don't mind, but this way everything's in one place without so much commentary.

Comment: @Neall you can also remove duplicate values by using distinct. The following query will only concatenate different employee names.
SELECT company_id, string_agg( distinct employee, ', ')
FROM mytable
GROUP BY company_id;

Answer (score 115):

How about using Postgres built-in array functions? At least on 8.4 this works out of the box:

```
SELECT company_id, array_to_string(array_agg(employee), ',')
FROM mytable
GROUP BY company_id;
```

Comment: sadly this doesn't work for us on Greenplum (v8.2).  +1 all the same

Comment: Works fine for me on Greenplum 4.3.4.1 (built on PostgreSQL 8.2.15).

Answer (score 25):

As from PostgreSQL 9.0 you can use the aggregate function called [string_agg](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/functions-aggregate.html). Your new SQL should look something like this:

```
SELECT company_id, string_agg(employee, ', ')
FROM mytable
GROUP BY company_id;
```

Answer (score 15):

I claim no credit for the answer because I found it after some searching:

What I didn't know is that PostgreSQL allows you to define your own aggregate functions with [CREATE AGGREGATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-createaggregate.html)

[This post](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2003-09/msg00177.php) on the PostgreSQL list shows how trivial it is to create a function to do what's required:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE textcat_all(
  basetype    = text,
  sfunc       = textcat,
  stype       = text,
  initcond    = ''
);

SELECT company_id, textcat_all(employee || ', ')
FROM mytable
GROUP BY company_id;
```

Answer (score 7):

As already mentioned, creating your own aggregate function is the right thing to do. Here is my concatenation aggregate function (you can find [details in French](http://www.bortzmeyer.org/agregats-postgresql.html)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION concat2(text, text) RETURNS text AS '
    SELECT CASE WHEN $1 IS NULL OR $1 = \'\' THEN $2
            WHEN $2 IS NULL OR $2 = \'\' THEN $1
            ELSE $1 || \' / \' || $2
            END; 
'
 LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE AGGREGATE concatenate (
  sfunc = concat2,
  basetype = text,
  stype = text,
  initcond = ''
```

);

And then use it as:

```
SELECT company_id, concatenate(employee) AS employees FROM ...
```

Answer (score 5):

This latest announcement list snippet might be of interest if you'll be upgrading to 8.4:

> Until 8.4 comes out with a
>   super-effient native one, you can add
>   the array_accum() function in the
>   PostgreSQL documentation for rolling
>   up any column into an array, which can
>   then be used by application code, or
>   combined with array_to_string() to
>   format it as a list:
>
> http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xaggr.html

I'd link to the 8.4 development docs but they don't seem to list this feature yet.

Answer (score 5):

Following up on Kev's answer, using the Postgres docs:

First, create an array of the elements, then use the built-in `array_to_string` function.

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_accum (anyelement)
(
 sfunc = array_append,
 stype = anyarray,
 initcond = '{}'
);

select array_to_string(array_accum(name),'|') from table group by id;
```

Answer (score 5):

Following yet again on the use of a custom aggregate function of string concatenation: you need to remember that the select statement will place rows in any order, so you will need to do a sub *select* in the *from* statement with an *order by* clause, and then an outer *select* with a *group by* clause to aggregate the strings, thus:

```
SELECT custom_aggregate(MY.special_strings)
FROM (SELECT special_strings, grouping_column 
        FROM a_table 
        ORDER BY ordering_column) MY
GROUP BY MY.grouping_column
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `STRING_AGG` function for [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) and [Google BigQuery SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string_agg):

```
SELECT company_id, STRING_AGG(employee, ', ')
FROM employees
GROUP BY company_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this PostgreSQL documentation helpful: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/functions-conditional.html.

In my case, I sought plain SQL to concatenate a field with brackets around it, if the field is not empty.

```
select itemid, 
  CASE 
    itemdescription WHEN '' THEN itemname 
    ELSE itemname || ' (' || itemdescription || ')' 
  END 
from items;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Amazon Redshift, where string_agg is not supported, try using listagg.

```
SELECT company_id, listagg(EMPLOYEE, ', ') as employees
FROM EMPLOYEE_table
GROUP BY company_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to version PostgreSQL 9.0 and above you can use the aggregate function called string_agg. Your new SQL should look something like this:

```
SELECT company_id, string_agg(employee, ', ')
    FROM mytable GROUP BY company_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use format function. Which can also implicitly take care of  type conversion of text, int, etc by itself.

```
create or replace function concat_return_row_count(tbl_name text, column_name text, value int)
returns integer as $row_count$
declare
total integer;
begin
    EXECUTE format('select count(*) from %s WHERE %s = %s', tbl_name, column_name, value) INTO total;
    return total;
end;
$row_count$ language plpgsql;


postgres=# select concat_return_row_count('tbl_name','column_name',2); --2 is the value
```

Comment: How is this related to using an aggregate to concatenate string values?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Jetbrains Rider and it was a hassle copying the results from above examples to re-execute because it seemed to wrap it all in JSON. This joins them into a single statement that was easier to run

```
select string_agg('drop table if exists "' || tablename || '" cascade', ';') 
from pg_tables where schemaname != $$pg_catalog$$ and tableName like $$rm_%$$
```