# How to get multiple records against one record based on relation?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables Organisation and Employee having one to many relation i.e one organisation can have multiple employees. Now I want to select all information of a particular organisation plus first name of all employees for this organisation. What’s the best way to do it? Can I get all of this in single record set or I will have to get multiple rows based on no. of employees? Here is a bit graphical demonstration of what I want:

```
Org_ID      Org_Address    Org_OtherDetails    Employess

1           132A B Road    List of details     Emp1, Emp2, Emp3.....
```

Answer (score 25):

The original question was database specific, but perhaps this is a good place to include a more generic answer. It's a common question. The concept that you are describing is often referred to as 'Group Concatenation'. There's no standard solution in SQL-92 or SQL-99. So you'll need a vendor-specific solution.

- **MySQL** - Use the built-in GROUP_CONCAT function. In your example you would want something like this:

```
select 
  o.ID, o.Address, o.OtherDetails,
  GROUP_CONCAT( concat(e.firstname, ' ', e.lastname) ) as Employees
from 
  employees e 
  inner join organization o on o.org_id=e.org_id
group by o.org_id
```

- **PostgreSQL** - PostgreSQL 9.0 is equally simple now that string_agg(expression, delimiter) is built-in. Here it is with 'comma-space' between elements:

```
select 
  o.ID, o.Address, o.OtherDetails,
  STRING_AGG( (e.firstname || ' ' || e.lastname), ', ' ) as Employees
from 
  employees e 
  inner join organization o on o.org_id=e.org_id
group by o.org_id
```

PostgreSQL before 9.0 allows you to define your own aggregate functions with CREATE AGGREGATE. Slightly more work than MySQL, but much more flexible. See this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query) for more details. (Of course PostgreSQL 9.0 and later have this option as well.)

- **Oracle** - same idea using **LISTAGG**.
- **MS SQL Server** - same idea using **STRING_AGG**
- **Fallback solution** - in other database technologies or in very very old versions of the technologies listed above you don't have these group concatenation functions. In that case create a stored procedure that takes the org_id as its input and outputs the concatenated employee names. Then use this stored procedure in your query. Some of the other responses here include some details about how to write stored procedures like these.

```
select 
  o.ID, o.Address, o.OtherDetails,
  MY_CUSTOM_GROUP_CONCAT_PROCEDURE( o.ID ) as Employees
from 
  organization o
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the question is tagged as MySQL, you should be able to use a MySQL-specific solution, namely, GROUP_CONCAT. For example,

```
select Org_ID, Org_Address, Org_OtherDetails,
       GROUP_CONCAT(employees) as Employees
from  employees a, organization b
where a.org_id=b.org_id
group by b.org_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

in MS SQL you can do:

```
create function dbo.table2list (@input int)
returns varchar(8000)
as
BEGIN
declare @putout varchar(8000)
set @putout = ''
select @putout = @putout + ', ' + <employeename>
from <employeetable>
where <orgid> = @input
return @putout
end
```

then do:

```
select * from org, dbo.table2list(orgid)
from <organisationtable>
```

I think you can do it with COALESCE() as well, but can't remember the syntax off the top of my head

Comment: Of course, as soon as the total of all your employees names, plus commas and spaces reaches 8000 - you've got a problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Oracle you can create a PL/SQL function you can use in your query that accepts an organization_id as input, and returns the first name of all employees belonging to that org as a string. For example:-

```
select
   o.org_id,
   o.org_address,
   o.org_otherdetails,
   org_employees( o.org_id ) as org_employees
from
   organization o
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends. 
If you do a join, you get all the organization data on every row. (1 row per employee). That has a cost.
If you do two queries. (Org and Emp) that has a different cost.

Pick your poison.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no".

As noted in other answers, there are vendor-specific ways to achieve this result, but there is no pure SQL solution which works in one query.

sorry about that  :(

Presumably one of the vendor specific solutions will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do, you have 2 options:

```
select *
FROM
  users u
  LEFT JOIN organizations o ON (u.idorg = o.id);
```

This way you will get extra data on each row - full organization info you don't really need.

Or you can do:

```
select o.*, group_concat(u.name)
FROM
  users u
  LEFT JOIN organizations o ON (u.idorg = o.id)
GROUP BY
  o.id
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

The second approach is applicable if you want to see ie. list of usernames "user1, user2, user3", but don't want to operate on the fields themselves...

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server SQLCLR aggregates in this project are inspired by the MSDN code sample however they perform much better and allow for sorting (as strings) and alternate delimiters if needed. They offer *almost* equivalent functionality to MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT for SQL Server.

A full comparison of the advantages/disadvantages of the CLR aggregates and the FOR XML solution can be found in the documentation:

http://groupconcat.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2017 & Azure SQL there is now a function STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL) for this to be on par more with MySQL:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.

```
SELECT attribute1, STRING_AGG (attribute2, '|') AS Attribute2
FROM  table
GROUP BY attribute
```