# Perl JOIN-like behavior in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, join

I have two tables, let's call them PERSON and NAME.

```
 PERSON
  person_id
  dob

 NAME
  name_id
  person_id
  name
```

And let's say that the NAME table has data like:

```
name_id  person_id  name
1        1          Joe
2        1          Fred
3        1          Sam
4        2          Jane
5        2          Kim
```

I need a query (Oracle 10g) that will return

```
name_id   names
1         Joe, Fred, Sam
2         Jane, Kim
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

---

Update:

According to the article that figs was kind enough to provide, starting in 9i you can do:

```
SELECT wmsys.wm_concat(dname) departments FROM dept;
```

For this example, the answer becomes:

```
SELECT name_id,  wmsys.wm_concat(name) from names group by name_id
```

Comment: You might find [this article](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/one-row.html) to be helpful.

Comment: Don't you mean person_id in that query result?

Comment: Beware.  The output type changed on wm_concat() in recent patches from varchar to lob.  Casting it back to char works though.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/one-row.html

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to use a PL/SQL function. For more details, have a look in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102317/how-to-get-multiple-records-against-one-record-based-on-relation) post.