# How to return multiple values in one column (T-SQL)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table `UserAliases` (`UserId, Alias`) with multiple aliases per user. I need to query it and return all aliases for a given user, the trick is to return them all in one column.

Example:

```
UserId/Alias  
1/MrX  
1/MrY  
1/MrA  
2/Abc  
2/Xyz
```

I want the query result in the following format:

```
UserId/Alias  
1/ MrX, MrY, MrA  
2/ Abc, Xyz
```

Thank you.

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

p.s. actual T-SQL query would be appreciated :)

Comment: Related question (for others with the same problem): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102317/how-to-get-multiple-records-against-one-record-based-on-relation

Comment: I am way too late but check this out - [the cleanest way yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276949/1270970)

Comment: SqlServer 2017 now has [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) that aggregates multiple strings into one using a given separator.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use a function with COALESCE.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAliasesById]
(
    @userID int
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @output varchar(max)
    select @output = COALESCE(@output + ', ', '') + alias
    from UserAliases
    where userid = @userID

    return @output
END

GO

SELECT UserID, dbo.GetAliasesByID(UserID)
FROM UserAliases
GROUP BY UserID

GO
```

Comment: In this case if i use order by case in UserAliases table it is possible for i try but not success if another way to use "order by alias" in select statement any solution .. Please ...

Comment: I know this is old, but how could we make it default to ORDER BY ascending order?, it seems to always come as descending

Answer (score 21):

Well... I see that an answer was already accepted... but I think you should see another solutions anyway:

```
/* EXAMPLE */
DECLARE @UserAliases TABLE(UserId INT , Alias VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @UserAliases (UserId,Alias) SELECT 1,'MrX'
     UNION ALL SELECT 1,'MrY' UNION ALL SELECT 1,'MrA'
     UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Abc' UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Xyz'

/* QUERY */
;WITH tmp AS ( SELECT DISTINCT UserId FROM @UserAliases )
SELECT 
    LEFT(tmp.UserId, 10) +
    '/ ' +
    STUFF(
            (   SELECT ', '+Alias 
                FROM @UserAliases 
                WHERE UserId = tmp.UserId 
                FOR XML PATH('') 
            ) 
            , 1, 2, ''
        ) AS [UserId/Alias]
FROM tmp

/* -- OUTPUT
  UserId/Alias
  1/ MrX, MrY, MrA
  2/ Abc, Xyz    
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Str varchar(500)

SELECT @Str=COALESCE(@Str,'') + CAST(ID as varchar(10)) + ','
FROM dbo.fcUser

SELECT @Str
```

Answer (score 0):

group_concat() sounds like what you're looking for.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

since you're on mssql, i just googled "group_concat mssql" and found a bunch of hits to recreate group_concat functionality.  here's one of the hits i found:

http://www.stevenmapes.com/index.php?/archives/23-Recreating-MySQL-GROUP_CONCAT-In-MSSQL-Cross-Tab-Query.html

Comment: the question is targeted at MS-SQL

Comment: But the answer contains information on how to find a similar function in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You can either loop through the rows with a cursor and append to a field in a temp table, or you could use the COALESCE function to concatenate the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, read the question wrong the first time.  You can do something like this:

```
declare @result varchar(max)

--must "initialize" result for this to work
select @result = ''

select @result = @result + alias
FROM aliases
WHERE username='Bob'
```