# Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

Using `MySQL`, I can do something like:

```
SELECT hobbies FROM peoples_hobbies WHERE person_id = 5;
```

**My Output:**

```
shopping
fishing
coding
```

but instead I just want 1 row, 1 col:

**Expected Output:**

```
shopping, fishing, coding
```

The reason is that I'm selecting multiple values from multiple tables, and after all the joins I've got a lot more rows than I'd like.

I've looked for a function on [MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) and it doesn't look like the `CONCAT` or `CONCAT_WS` functions accept result sets.

So does anyone here know how to do this?

Comment: I just wrote up a little demo on how to use group_concat which might be usefull to you: http://www.giombetti.com/2013/06/06/mysql-group_concat/

Comment: this may help you https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Comment: you can use xpath to pivot rows in columns

Answer (score 2092, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT person_id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(hobbies SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM peoples_hobbies
GROUP BY person_id;
```

As Ludwig stated in [his comment,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field#comment14513101_276949) you can add the `DISTINCT` operator to avoid duplicates:

```
SELECT person_id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT hobbies SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM peoples_hobbies
GROUP BY person_id;
```

As Jan stated in [their comment,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field#comment72475644_276949) you can also sort the values before imploding it using `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT person_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(hobbies ORDER BY hobbies ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM peoples_hobbies
GROUP BY person_id;
```

As Dag stated in [his comment,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field/276949#comment12638055_276949) there is a 1024 byte limit on the result. To solve this, run this query before your query:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 2048;
```

Of course, you can change `2048` according to your needs. To calculate and assign the value:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = CAST(
                     (SELECT SUM(LENGTH(hobbies)) + COUNT(*) * LENGTH(', ')
                           FROM peoples_hobbies
                           GROUP BY person_id) AS UNSIGNED);
```

Comment: Just be aware of the limitation of 1024 bytes in the resulting column (see parameter [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len))

Comment: And adding the `DISTINCT` parameter, you will not get any doubles.
`... GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT hobbies)`

Comment: I got the same results even while omitting the `GROUP BY person_id` clause at the end.

Answer (score 126):

Have a look at `GROUP_CONCAT` if your MySQL version (4.1) supports it. See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for more details.

It would look something like:

```
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(hobbies SEPARATOR ', ') 
  FROM peoples_hobbies 
  WHERE person_id = 5 
  GROUP BY 'all';
```

Comment: I think that `group by 'all'` isn't necessary (moreover unwanted), because this assign to all rows string `all` and then compare strings between these rows. Am I right?

Answer (score 94):

I found myself wanting to **select multiple, individual rows**—instead of a group—and concatenate on a certain field.

#### Given:

Let's say you have a table of product ids and their names and prices:

```
+------------+--------------------+-------+
| product_id | name               | price |
+------------+--------------------+-------+
|         13 | Double Double      |     5 |
|         14 | Neapolitan Shake   |     2 |
|         15 | Animal Style Fries |     3 |
|         16 | Root Beer          |     2 |
|         17 | Lame T-Shirt       |    15 |
+------------+--------------------+-------+
```

Then you have some fancy-schmancy ajax that lists these puppies off as checkboxes.

Your hungry-hippo user selects `13, 15, 16`. No dessert for her today...

#### Find:

A way to summarize your user's order in one line, with pure mysql.

#### Solution:

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` with the [the `IN` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ' + ') AS order_summary FROM product WHERE product_id IN (13, 15, 16);
```

Which outputs:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| order_summary                                  |
+------------------------------------------------+
| Double Double + Animal Style Fries + Root Beer |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

#### Bonus Solution:

If you want the total price too, toss in [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum):

```
mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ' + ') AS order_summary, SUM(price) AS total FROM product WHERE product_id IN (13, 15, 16);
+------------------------------------------------+-------+
| order_summary                                  | total |
+------------------------------------------------+-------+
| Double Double + Animal Style Fries + Root Beer |    10 |
+------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Even though this is a good answer, this sounds more like advertising than purely answering. Still a good well-formated answer.

Comment: How is this related to the OP's question?

Answer (score 41):

You can change the max length of the `GROUP_CONCAT` value by setting the `group_concat_max_len` parameter.

See details in the [MySQL documantation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Answer (score 31):

There's a GROUP Aggregate function, [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Answer (score 28):

In my case I had a row of Ids, and it was neccessary to cast it to char, otherwise, the result was encoded into binary format :

```
SELECT CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(field SEPARATOR ',') AS CHAR) FROM table
```

Answer (score 20):

I had a more complicated query, and found that I had to use `GROUP_CONCAT` in an outer query to get it to work:

### Original Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userID 
FROM event GROUP BY userID 
HAVING count(distinct(cohort))=2);
```

### Imploded:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sub.userID SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM event 
GROUP BY userID HAVING count(distinct(cohort))=2) as sub;
```

Hope this might help someone.

Answer (score 19):

Use MySQL(5.6.13) session variable and assignment operator like the following

```
SELECT @logmsg := CONCAT_ws(',',@logmsg,items) FROM temp_SplitFields a;
```

then you can get

```
test1,test11
```

Comment: is it faster than GROUP_CONCAT ?

Comment: I tested this under PHPMyAdmin with MySQL server v5.6.17 on a _description_ column (varchar(50)) in a _test_ table but it returns a BLOB field for each record: `SELECT @logmsg := CONCAT_ws(',',@logmsg,description)  
from test`

Answer (score 14):

For somebody looking here how to use `GROUP_CONCAT` with subquery - posting this example

```
SELECT i.*,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(userid) FROM favourites f WHERE f.itemid = i.id) AS idlist
FROM items i
WHERE i.id = $someid
```

So `GROUP_CONCAT` must be used inside the subquery, not wrapping it.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Hobbies NVARCHAR(200) = ' '

SELECT @Hobbies = @Hobbies + hobbies + ',' FROM peoples_hobbies WHERE person_id = 5;
```

TL;DR;

```
set @sql='';
set @result='';
set @separator=' union \r\n';
SELECT 
@sql:=concat('select ''',INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME  ,''' as col_name,',
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH ,' as def_len ,' ,
'MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(',INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME , '))as  max_char_len',
' FROM ',
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
) as sql_piece, if(@result:=if(@result='',@sql,concat(@result,@separator,@sql)),'','') as dummy
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.DATA_TYPE like '%char%'
and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_SCHEMA='xxx' 
and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME='yyy';
select @result;
```

Comment: This is what I got : 'Unrecognized statement type. (near "DECLARE" at position 0)'

Answer (score 2):

we have two way to concatenate columns in MySql

```
select concat(hobbies) as `Hobbies` from people_hobbies where 1
```

Or

```
select group_concat(hobbies) as `Hobbies` from people_hobbies where 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It is late but will helpfull for those who are searching "concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field using pivot table" :)

Query:

```
SELECT pm.id, pm.name, GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) as channel_names
FROM payment_methods pm
LEFT JOIN payment_methods_channels_pivot pmcp ON pmcp.payment_method_id = pm.id
LEFT JOIN channels c ON c.id = pmcp.channel_id
GROUP BY pm.id
```

Tables

```
payment_methods 
  id  | name
  1   | PayPal

channels
  id  | name
  1   | Google
  2   | Faceook

payment_methods_channels_pivot
   payment_method_id | channel_id
   1                 |  1
   1                 |  2
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(c.name)` works which concatenating multiple rows into one column

Answer (score 2):

Here, my intension was to apply string concatenation without using group_concat() function:

```
Set @concatHobbies = '';
SELECT TRIM(LEADING ', ' FROM T.hobbies ) FROM 
(
   select 
   Id, @concatHobbies := concat_ws(', ',@concatHobbies,hobbies) as hobbies
   from peoples_hobbies
)T
Order by Id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Here

```
   select 
   Id, @concatHobbies := concat_ws(', ',@concatHobbies,hobbies) as hobbies
   from peoples_hobbies
```

will return

```
  Id    hobbies
  1     , shopping
  2     , shopping, fishing
  3     , shopping, fishing, coding
```

Now our expected result is at third position. So I am taking the Last row by using

```
  Order by Id DESC 
  LIMIT 1
```

Then I am also removing the First ', ' from my string

```
 TRIM(LEADING ', ' FROM T.hobbies )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting example in this case -

Following is the structure of the sample table `people_hobbies` -

```
DESCRIBE people_hobbies;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ppl_id  | int unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name    | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| hby_id  | int unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| hobbies | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The table is populated as follows -

```
SELECT * FROM people_hobbies;
+----+--------+-----------------+--------+-----------+
| id | ppl_id | name            | hby_id | hobbies   |
+----+--------+-----------------+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 | Shriya Jain     |      1 | reading   |
|  2 |      4 | Shirley Setia   |      4 | coding    |
|  3 |      2 | Varsha Tripathi |      7 | gardening |
|  4 |      3 | Diya Ghosh      |      2 | fishing   |
|  5 |      4 | Shirley Setia   |      3 | gaming    |
|  6 |      1 | Shriya Jain     |      6 | cycling   |
|  7 |      2 | Varsha Tripathi |      1 | reading   |
|  8 |      3 | Diya Ghosh      |      5 | shopping  |
|  9 |      3 | Diya Ghosh      |      4 | coding    |
| 10 |      4 | Shirley Setia   |      1 | reading   |
| 11 |      1 | Shriya Jain     |      4 | coding    |
| 12 |      1 | Shriya Jain     |      3 | gaming    |
| 13 |      4 | Shirley Setia   |      2 | fishing   |
| 14 |      4 | Shirley Setia   |      7 | gardening |
| 15 |      2 | Varsha Tripathi |      3 | gaming    |
| 16 |      2 | Varsha Tripathi |      2 | fishing   |
| 17 |      1 | Shriya Jain     |      5 | shopping  |
| 18 |      1 | Shriya Jain     |      7 | gardening |
| 19 |      3 | Diya Ghosh      |      1 | reading   |
| 20 |      4 | Shirley Setia   |      5 | shopping  |
+----+--------+-----------------+--------+-----------+
```

Now, a table `hobby_list` is generated having the list of all people and a list of each person's hobbies with each hobby in a new line -

```
CREATE TABLE hobby_list AS
    -> SELECT ppl_id, name,
    -> GROUP_CONCAT(hobbies ORDER BY hby_id SEPARATOR "\n")
    -> AS hobbies
    -> FROM people_hobbies
    -> GROUP BY ppl_id
    -> ORDER BY ppl_id;
```

```
SELECT * FROM hobby_list;
```

[image: CONCAT_GROUP()]

Answer (score 1):

Use **GROUP_CONCAT**:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(hobbies) FROM peoples_hobbies WHERE person_id = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

In sql server use string_agg to pivot a row field values into a column:

```
select string_agg(field1, ', ') a FROM mytable 

or

select string_agg(field1, ', ') within group (order by field1 dsc) a FROM mytable group by field2
```