# Query-generated tables with many-to-many data fields, best practice?

Tags: php, html-table, many-to-many

You have two hypothetical tables:

```
TABLE 1
[id]  [item]  [amount]  [cost]
 1     hat     20        10
 2     shoe    7         45
 3     belt    2         25

TABLE 2 (many to many)
[item]  [color]
 hat     blue
 hat     red
 hat     yellow
 shoe    black
 shoe    white
 etc.    etc.
```

and when you run a query, you want to output a list that includes all of both data like this:

```
[ITEM]  [AMOUNT]  [COST]  [AVAILABLE COLORS]
 hat     20        10      blue, red, yellow
 shoe    7         45      black, white
 etc.
```

If the colors weren't present, it'd be a single query to grab all that info from one table and process the array in a loop. But to accommodate `TABLE 2` I can think of two ways to do it:

**Brute Force:** run a query for every single return to get the data from `TABLE 2`, add commas, and insert it into the results array from `TABLE 1`, then output HTML table

**Ugly Workaround:** add a new column to `Table 1` and periodically update with strings of data from `Table 2` behind the scenes

...there's a better way, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with MySQL, the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function might interest you.

See for instance this question : [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Else, the "brute force" solution you described is generally the one that's used -- a possible optimization being to do only 1 query to get lines from the second table that correspond to all lines from the first table at once.

For instance, you'd :

- do the query to get that data from the first table
- do one query to get all data from the second table that correspond to data from the first table -- something like `select * from table_2 where item in ('hat', 'shoe', 'belt')`
- use a loop on the PHP side to "re-attach" results from the second query to the results from the first one

With this solution, you'll do a bit more work on the PHP side, but only 2 queries -- instead of 1 + (number of lines returned from the first query) ; which is generally much better, when you have lots of lines returned from the first query.

Comment: Oooh! I *like* the idea of stripping Table2 in one large query and then having PHP do all the grouping and insertion. Obviously hadn't thought of that! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome :-)  ;; that's a solution I've used a couple of times ; going from O(n) queries to O(constant) often feels nice ^^ *(of course, don't forget to profile both solutions -- but less queries is generally better)*