# MySQL Count GET ALL ROWS

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get all rows that have `count(AID)>5`
When i do the query as :

```
SELECT x,y,z, COUNT(AID) as total from Table where ... Having total >5
```

It return the rows With `total > 5` grouped ! but not all rows !
I want each row ..

Comment: Do you want all rows that are > 5 or do you want a count of AID grouped by all rows?  Your question isn't clear.

Comment: What's your question? I didn't understand.

Comment: if i did select with count it will return on row which has the count but i actually want all rows which applies on having !

Comment: We have a rash of these questions that aren't questions recently...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how aggregate queries work. The count is done over a range of records (whichever ones meet the conditions of the `WHERE` clause) and then the `HAVING` clause filters out anything with a count less than 5. If you want the specific rows that contributed to the count you might try something like

```
select * from
`Table`, 
(SELECT x,y,z, COUNT(AID) as total
   from `Table`
   where /* Some condition goes here */
   Having total >5) subqry
where subqry.x = Table.x
and subqry.Y = Table.Y
and subqry.Z = Table.Z
```

...of course, this assumes that `x,y,z` are a unique key for `Table`. If this is not the case, then this approach may not work.

Also, are you missing a `group by` clause?