# SQL Query & Multiple results for one record

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to join multiple tables together but I'm having a bit of trouble when certain products have more than 1 picture attached them them.

```
Products                        Pictures
Id                              pic_id
name                            pic_name
picture_id
```

My query:

```
SELECT id, name, pic_name
FROM Products 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Pictures p ON id=pic_id
```

That displays something like

```
1   RAM  ram.png
1   RAM  ram2.png
1   RAM  ram4.png
2   CPU  test.png
```

I'd like to display something like

```
1   RAM  ram.png, ram2.png, ram4, png
2   CPU  test.png
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Search for `sql pivot` on this site.

Comment: You could also possibly use the COALESCE function. What database server are you using please?

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer, but there is already a post on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field - the GROUP_CONCAT function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something close to this should work for you:

```
SELECT prod.id, prod.name, GROUP_CONCAT( pic.pic_name )
FROM Products AS prod
LEFT OUTER JOIN Pictures AS pic ON prod.picture_id = pic.pic_id 
GROUP BY prod.id, prod.name
```

Comment: It's achieving the same results in my original post. Listing as      1   RAM  ram.png
1   RAM  ram2.png
1   RAM  ram4.png
2   CPU  test.png

Comment: You can avoid the join if you use the GROUP_CONCAT function - been using it a lot recently, very similar to the hacky use of COALESCE in SQL Server :-)

Comment: I don't want to see the id repeated in rows. Just 1 row, if it contains multiple pictures that they show in "pictures" header all together.

Comment: where is it getting the pic_name from you're not referencing Pictures table

Comment: @ManuelDiaz I've updated my answer, I believe this should be what you're hoping for

Comment: Absolutely right, that's why I upvoted yours. Actually just wanted to point out the missing Group By.

Comment: Thanks both for the amazing help! Some pretty nifty stuff here :)

Comment: @Adam Wenger- Group by is on  prod.id, prod.name, How to pass pic.pic_name to a function in select without group on pic.pic_name?

Comment: @RedHat Columns you are passing to aggregate functions do not need to be in `GROUP BY`; it is the other columns not in an aggregate function that need to be in a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Adam Wenger- Hmm, I think GROUP_CONCAT is a user function! I not see beforehand. Thanks, I voted up.

Comment: @RedHat [GROUP_CONCAT is described here for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this site to see how to use the pivots in mysql: 
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table