# convert multi row result set to one row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transform

it's a noob question so hope somebody can help on this

I want to transform the resultset from the query which has a multiple lines for one user to a single row of data for one activity

i get this data

```
userid, date,      activity_id, parameter_id,   parameter_value
545,  2011/9/11,  1,    4, 20
545,    2011/9/11,  1,  5, 10,
545,  2011/9/11,  1,  6, 30,
```

i want it to convert to

```
userid, date,   activity_id,  parameter_4_id_value, parameter_5_id_value, parameter_6_id_value
545,    2011/9/11,  1, 20,10,30
```

any example will be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: The #first method will give you the first item in an array, or select for the first item in a query.

Comment: the first item is a query result set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about pulling data from MySQL you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to do something like this. See this other answer for an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/276949/511203