# PHP / MySQL: Joining three tables and merging results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

I have three tables:

Table #1: `teacher`

```
id
firstname
surname
```

Table #2: `course`

```
id
name
```

Table #3: `courses_has_teachers`

```
course_id
teacher_id
```

What I want to get, is the course info with the teacher(s) info. I have tried it with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
teacher, course, courses_has_teachers
WHERE
courses_has_teachers.teacher_id = teacher.id
AND
course.id = courses_has_teachers.course.id
```

I get what I want, BUT: if a course has more than one teacher, I want to combine the results. Instead of multiple rows with same course info, I want to get one simple row with course info and a list of teachers.

**NOT like this:**

```
Name      | Teacher
--------------------
Course 1  | Person 1
Course 1  | Person 2
```

**BUT this:**

```
Name      | Teacher
------------------------------
Course 1  | Person 1, Person 2
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: You can use GROUP BY Name and the GROUP_CONCAT(Teacher) function.

Comment: you dont actually need that third table; you can include a foreign key to `teacher_id` in `course`

Comment: @Hiroto: of course he needs the 3rd table, since one course can have multiple teachers.

Comment: @OP: what you want to achieve is really unSQLish. What you've got and you consider wrong, is actually OK.

Comment: @Flavius you can put an index on the name in have multiple entries with different IDs and a non-unique course_id

Comment: @Hiroto will that still be normalized (up to 3rd NF at least)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`. try this one,

```
SELECT  a.name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', surname))
FROM    course a
        INNER JOIN courses_has_teachers b
            ON a.id = b.course_id
        INNER JOIN teacher c
            ON b.teacher_id = c.iD
GROUP BY a.name
```

Comment: Mind explaining why this answer has been downvoted?

Comment: Yeah, I was curious why our two answers just got slapped.

Comment: @Fluffeh nevermind, some people just drop by and downvotes without leaving any comment, makes them feel happy. glad we could make them happy. haha :D

Comment: @user1428033 `GROUP_CONCAT` is different from `CONCAT`. The first one is an aggregate function while the other is not. Anyway, you are welcome. feel free to ask question where you get confused :)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a mysql function called group_concat to achieve this. Your query will look something similar to this:

```
SELECT courseName, group_concat(teacherName) FROM 
teacher, course, courses_has_teachers
WHERE
courses_has_teachers.teacher_id = teacher.id
AND
course.id = courses_has_teachers.course.id
GROUP BY courseName
```

I have re-written this query in ANSI-92 format, which you might not be familiar with, but is can make queries with multiple joins *SO* much easier to read:

```
SELECT 
    courseName, 
    group_concat(teacherName) 
FROM 
    teacher
        join course
            on courses_has_teachers.teacher_id = teacher.id
        join courses_has_teachers
            on course.id = courses_has_teachers.course.id
WHERE
    // Any conditions you want on the query
GROUP BY
    courseName
```

Additionally, you might want to have a read of a [lengthy Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) that I wrote which you might find useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try using **[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)** and **[GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)**.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I like answers to the official documentation. "the essential parts" is bullshit, if that link disappears, mysql would have disappeared altogether (or the explanations which you'd put in your answer would be outdated anyway).