# SQL data in one field separated by coma

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

I have three tables items, sizes and item_sizes for many to many relationship with join i can query this:

```
item     size
shirt    L
shirt    XL
dress    S
dress    L
dress    XL
```

But i want this:

```
item     size
shirt    L, XL
dress    S, L, XL
```

Speed doesn't matter i want only the results.I can do it with while loop but is there another way of doing this query?

Comment: which platform? as there's a built in mysql funtion for that: GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: @jenson-button-event you mean doing a function with a while loop?I can do that but is possible to do it with a query?

Comment: @antonio, seems you have your answer (see below)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select item, group_concat(size)
from the_table
group by item;
```

More details in the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 4):

Try [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

```
SELECT item, GROUP_CONCAT(size)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY item
```

Answer (score 4):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEEXample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fd4b/6)**

```
SELECT item,
       group_concat(size separator ', ') AS SIZE
FROM Table1
GROUP BY item
```

Result:

```
|  ITEM |     SIZE |
--------------------
| dress | S, L, XL |
| shirt |    L, XL |
```