# Complicated M:N relationship with MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

**Table**: news
**fields**: uid, title, categories, datetime, hidden, deleted

**Table**: categories_mn
**fields**: uid_local, uid_foreign

**Table**: categories
**Fields**: uid, parentcategory, name, image

Every news entry can be assigned to several different categories.

What Im trying to achieve is to get the latest 3 news, and show the image of all the categories that this entry is assigned to (and have a Image assigned)

Something like this:

```
title  | catimages           |
------------------------------
Post 7 | cat1.jpg            |
Post 6 |                     |
Post 5 | cat1.jpg,cat3.jpg   |
------------------------------
```

This is all I have so far:

```
SELECT title, categories
FROM news
WHERE deleted = 0 AND hidden = 0 AND
ORDER BY datetime DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Im not very experienced with SQL. Please help.

Comment: What is the `categories` field? And also what is the `uid_local` and `uid_foreign`?

Comment: The `categories` field is the uid_local of the M:N relationship table. The other field is the uid of the categories table.

Comment: @Dbugger Use group_concat if you want to concate your catimages, i.e. if you want to get cat1.jpg,cat3.jpg. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field

Comment: That was indeed the answer, Mr. Radical. Put it in an answer, so I can give you credit :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.title, b.categories, a.image from categories a
inner join news b
on a.uid=b.uid
WHERE b.deleted = 0 and b.hidden = 0
order by a.datetime desc
limit 3;
```

Comment: I unmarked this as solution. This doesn#t work. It should have been obvious from the beginning, since you make no use whatsoever of the mn table

Comment: No. I executed your query and it "appeared" to be working properly. But after further testing, I realize i was being deceived by proper output, fruit of coincidence.

Comment: Very good..sorry I couldn't be of more assistance, It seems you have found your answer above ^^. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the categories column in the news table.
I think this query should work:

```
SELECT 
    news.title, 
    categories.image 
FROM 
    news 
    INNER JOIN categories_mn ON news.uid=categories.uid_local 
    INNER JOIN categories ON categories.uid=categories_mn.uid_foreign 
WHERE 
    news.hidden=0 AND news.deleted=0 
ORDER BY 
    datetime DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

I'd also rename the columns in categories_mn so that it's clearer which column refers to which table. Maybe `uid_news` and `uid_categories` are good names which also help better understand the m:n relation...