# Join on piped column data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to work with a MySQL database where some columns have different IDs saved in one column, separated by a piped character. For example:

***Users table:***

```
id | username | groups
1  | user1    | 1|2|3|5
```

The group IDs correspond to groups. It shows in what groups a user is placed in. So there is also a `Groups` table:

***Groups table:***

```
id | groupname
1  | group1
2  | group2
3  | group3
4  | group4
5  | group5
```

What i'd like to do is select a user and then select all the `groupnames` that this user is placed in, something like a `JOIN`. For `user1` this is ***all*** groups ***except*** `group4`.

This would obviously be easier if the groups were saved in another table called `user_groups`, which could look like this:

***user_groups table:***

```
fk_user_id | fk_group_id
1          | 1
1          | 2
1          | 3
1          | 5
```

But, unfortunately i cannot change the database schema since an entire system is already based in this.

I'd like to know if there is a smart way of getting all the groupnames when selecting a user in a single query. For example a result could look something like this:

```
id | username | groups  | groupnames
1  | user1    | 1|2|3|5 | group1|group2|group3|group5
```

Is it possible somehow to do something like this in one query with MySQL?

Comment: maybe half of your problem can be done like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field

Comment: there are hundreds of these type of questions on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use `find_in_set()` for this type of join:

```
select *
from user u join
     groups g
     on find_in_set(g.groupname, u.groups) > 0;
```

In MySQL, or other databases, you can use `like` as well:

```
select *
from user u join
     groups g
     on concat('|', g.groupname, '|') like concat('%|', u.groups, '|%');
```