# MySQL concat with an INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, inner-join, concatenation

I have 2 tables: **manuscript** and **manuscript_log**.

I would like to display for **each manuscript** the **corresponding logs on the same line**.

Example: 
I have two manuscripts 1 and 2. 
The manuscript 1 has 2 logs and the manuscript 2 has 3 logs.

I would like to get two results in the query, grouped by the manuscrit id:

```
manuscript_id     manuscript_log
1.                      1,2
2.                     3,4,5

SELECT manuscript.id, manuscript_log.log_number
FROM manuscript INNER JOIN manuscript_log
              ON manuscript.id = manuscript_log.manuscript_id
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field for a hugely more upvoted question/answer on the identical issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function

```
SELECT manuscript.id, GROUP_CONCAT(manuscript_log.log_number)
FROM manuscript INNER JOIN manuscript_log
              ON manuscript.id = manuscript_log.manuscript_id
GROUP BY manuscript.id
```

Comment: i suggest a modification to use `group_concat(distinct manuscript_log.log_number order by manuscript_log.log_number separator ',')`

Comment: Playing around a bit with this i found out you can also concat multiple fields inside the group_concat like this `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT manuscript_log.log_number, ' ', manuscript_log.some_other_key_eg_email separator '; ')` only thing though is that the distinct field is always first... hope that helps! ;)