# mysql join two table with comma separated ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

**Table 1**

```
ID     NAME
1      Person1
2      Person2
3      Person3
```

**Table 2**

```
ID     GROUP_ID
1      1
2      2,3
```

The IDs in all the columns above refer to the same ID (Example - a Department)

My Expected output (by joining both the tables)

```
GROUP_ID     NAME
1            Person1
2,3          Person2,Person3
```

Is there a query with which i can achieve this. Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` on this,

```
SELECT  b.Group_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) name
FROM    Table2 b
        INNER JOIN Table1 a
            ON FIND_IN_SET(a.ID, b.Group_ID) > 0
GROUP   BY b.Group_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61a338/1)
- [MySQL FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)
- [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════╗
║ GROUP_ID ║      NAME       ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╣
║ 1        ║ Person1         ║
║ 2,3      ║ Person2,Person3 ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════╝
```

As a sidenote, this query might not perform efficiently as expected. Please do normalize your table properly by not saving values separated by a comma.

**UPDATE**

`GROUP_ID` is pretty much confusing. Isn't it `PersonIDList`? Anyway, here's my suggested schema design:

**PERSON Table**

- **PersonID (PK)**
- PersonName
- *other columns..*

**GROUP Table**

- **GroupID (PK)**
- GroupName
- *other columns..*

**PERSON_GROUP Table**

- PersonID (FK) (at the same time PK with column GroupID)
- GroupID (FK)

Comment: This is great, though it is important to observe the performance. +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestions. The previous developer who worked on this little software messed up the table structures. But surely i would consider normalizing the tables. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I like the `FIND_IN_SET` option since you are using MySQL, but here is an alternative solution that works as well using `LIKE` in the `JOIN`:

```
select t2.group_id, group_concat(t1.name order by t1.name separator ',' ) name
from t1 inner join t2 
  on concat(',',t2.group_id,',') like concat('%,',t1.id,',%') 
group by t2.group_id;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b584/1)

I would suggest you look into normalizing your data -- storing a comma delimited list in a relational database is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative.