# Can I resolve this with pure mysql? (joining on ';' separated values in a column)

Tags: mysql, join

To make a long story short: I have data in several tables that I need to grab together, I have simplified them for the purpose of not having to draw a huge table.

I need to do so in one query, and I can't use PHP or any other langauge to work with the results. (I would have used PHP if I could to simply work my way around this)

This wouldn't have been an issue if I were to have a link table that connects the t1 rows to t2 but unfortunately I don't and can't introduce one either.

```
User table: (alias t1)
user(varchar 150),resources(varchar 250)
+-------+-------+
| user1 | 1;2;4 |
+-------+-------+
| user2 | 2     |
+-------+-------+
| user3 | 3;4   |
+-------+-------+

Resources table: (alias t2)
id(int 11 AI), data(text)
+---+-------+
| 1 | data1 |
+---+-------+
| 2 | data2 |
+---+-------+
| 3 | data3 |
+---+-------+
| 4 | data4 |
+---+-------+
| 5 | data5 |
+---+-------+
```

Multiple users can be connected to the same resources, and users can access one or more resources.

I would like a result close to:

```
user,data
+-------+-------+
| user1 | data1 |
+-------+-------+
| user1 | data2 |
+-------+-------+
| user1 | data4 |
+-------+-------+
| user2 | data2 |
+-------+-------+
```

....etc etc.

I have basic mysql knowledge but this one is out of my knowledge scope. Is there any way I can inner join t2 ?

Threads I've read before making this post:
[How to join two tables using a comma-separated-list in the join field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861258/how-to-join-two-tables-using-a-comma-separated-list-in-the-join-field)

[mysql join two table with comma separated ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909248/mysql-join-two-table-with-comma-separated-ids)

Comment: If you could convert your `user table (t1)`, by using a sub-query,  into a 'proper table', then could  you solve it in one query? If so, the problem becomes the issue of converting the `user1 | 1;2;4` into 'rows'. Is that possible in standard SQL. Yes, if you join it with a table of sequential 'integers'. I call in 'integerseries'. I would put it in a view initially while I tested it. I haven't tried it but it should work.

Comment: It would help if you setup an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with test data. I want to get quickly to testing queries not setting up tables and testdata. I did a similar thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29969124/3184785)

Comment: @RyanVincent , Will do later today when I have a pc available, at the moment I made this post sqlfiddle was unreachable :(

Comment: @RyanVincent http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52d9b

Comment: I have been wanting to come up with a general technique for dealing with these 'delimited lists in a column' for some time. This question was the ideal opportunity to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Tidied it up and added a working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bd9d6/3).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the `user_resources` (t1) was a 'normalized table' with one row for each `user => resource` combination then the query to get the answer would be as simple as just `joining` the tables together.

Alas, it is `denormalized` by having the `resources` column as a: 'list of resource id' separated by a ';' character.

If we could convert the 'resources' column into rows then a lot of the difficulties go away as the table joins become simple.

**The query to generate the output asked for:**

```
SELECT user_resource.user, 
       resource.data

FROM user_resource 
     JOIN integerseries AS isequence 
       ON isequence.id <= COUNT_IN_SET(user_resource.resources, ';') /* normalize */

     JOIN resource 
       ON resource.id = VALUE_IN_SET(user_resource.resources, ';', isequence.id)      
ORDER BY
       user_resource.user,  resource.data
```

**The Output:**

```
user        data    
----------  --------
sampleuser  abcde   
sampleuser  azerty  
sampleuser  qwerty  
stacky      qwerty  
testuser    abcde   
testuser    azerty
```

*How:*

The 'trick' is to have a table that contains the numbers from 1 to some limit. I call it `integerseries`. It can be used to convert 'horizontal' things such as: `';' delimited strings` into `rows`.

The way this works is that when you 'join' with `integerseries`, you are doing a `cross join`, which is what happens 'naturally' with 'inner joins'.

Each row gets duplicated with a different 'sequence number' from the `integerseries` table which we use as an 'index' of the 'resource' in the list that we want to use for that `row`.

The idea is to:

- count the number of items in the list.
- extract each item based on its the position in the list.
- Use `integerseries` to convert one row into a set of rows extracting the individual 'resource id' from `user`.`resources` as we go along.

I decided to use two functions:

- function that given a 'delimited string list' and an 'index' will return the value at the position in the list. I call it: `VALUE_IN_SET`. i.e. given 'A;B;C' and an 'index' of 2 then it returns 'B'.
- function that given a 'delimited string list' will return the count of the number of items in the list. I call it: `COUNT_IN_SET`. i.e. given 'A;B;C' will return 3

It turns aout that those two functions and `integerseries` should provide a general solution to `delimited items list in a column`.

*Does it work?*

The query to create a 'normalized' table from a `';' delimited string in column`. It shows all the columns, including the generated values due to the 'cross_join' (`isequence.id` as  `resources_index`):

```
SELECT user_resource.user, 
       user_resource.resources,
       COUNT_IN_SET(user_resource.resources, ';')                AS resources_count, 
       isequence.id                                              AS resources_index,
       VALUE_IN_SET(user_resource.resources, ';', isequence.id)  AS resources_value
FROM 
     user_resource 
     JOIN  integerseries AS isequence 
       ON  isequence.id <= COUNT_IN_SET(user_resource.resources, ';')
ORDER BY
       user_resource.user, isequence.id
```

*The 'normalized' table output:*

```
user        resources  resources_count  resources_index  resources_value  
----------  ---------  ---------------  ---------------  -----------------
sampleuser  1;2;3                    3                1  1                
sampleuser  1;2;3                    3                2  2                
sampleuser  1;2;3                    3                3  3                
stacky      2                        1                1  2                
testuser    1;3                      2                1  1                
testuser    1;3                      2                2  3
```

Using the above 'normalized' `user_resources` table, it is a simple join to provide the output required:

*The functions needed* (*these are general functions that can be used anywhere*)

note: The names of these functions are related to the mysql [FIND_IN_SET  function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). i.e. they do similar things as regards string lists?

The **`COUNT_IN_SET`** function: returns the count of `character delimited items` in the column.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `COUNT_IN_SET`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `COUNT_IN_SET`(haystack VARCHAR(1024), 
                               delim CHAR(1)
                               ) RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
      RETURN CHAR_LENGTH(haystack) - CHAR_LENGTH( REPLACE(haystack, delim, '')) + 1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The **`VALUE_IN_SET`** function: treats the `delimited list` as a `one based array` and returns the value at the  given 'index'.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `VALUE_IN_SET`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `VALUE_IN_SET`(haystack VARCHAR(1024), 
                               delim CHAR(1), 
                               which INTEGER
                               ) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
BEGIN
      RETURN  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(haystack, delim, which),
                     delim,
                     -1);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Related Information:**

- Finally worked out how to get [SQLFiddle - working code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f279/1) to compile functions.
- There is a version of this that works for `SQLite` databases as well [SQLite- Normalizing a concatenated field and joining with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231542/sqlite-normalizing-a-concatenated-field-and-joining-with-it/34240021#34240021)

*The tables (with data):*

```
CREATE TABLE `integerseries` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=500 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

/*Data for the table `integerseries` */

insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (1);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (2);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (3);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (4);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (5);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (6);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (7);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (8);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (9);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (10);
```

Resource:

```
CREATE TABLE `resource` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

/*Data for the table `resource` */

insert  into `resource`(`id`,`data`) values (1,'abcde');
insert  into `resource`(`id`,`data`) values (2,'qwerty');
insert  into `resource`(`id`,`data`) values (3,'azerty');
```

User_resource:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_resource` (
  `user` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `resources` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

/*Data for the table `user_resource` */

insert  into `user_resource`(`user`,`resources`) values ('sampleuser','1;2;3');
insert  into `user_resource`(`user`,`resources`) values ('stacky','3');
insert  into `user_resource`(`user`,`resources`) values ('testuser','1;3');
```

Comment: I have redone this using functions and it is a lot neater. Will post the update soon.

Comment: Thank you for the great amount of effort you are putting into helping me out here :)
The view solution is enough to get my job done right now, but I'm really looking forward to your other solution, for learning purposes also. If you post this as a seperate answer, I can upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `;` with `,` you can use the FIND_IN_SET function to join your tables:

```sql
select u.user, r.data
from User u
join Resources r
  on find_in_set(r.id, replace(u.resources, ';', ','))
order by u.user, r.id
```

Result:

```sql
|  user |  data |
|-------|-------|
| user1 | data1 |
| user1 | data2 |
| user1 | data4 |
| user2 | data2 |
| user3 | data3 |
| user3 | data4 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0792b/5