# Fetching "Almost" similar results using your own value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, similarity

I am trying to fetch a list of results that has ALMOST similar value to the one I provides.

```
     id    |  food
1)    1       onions, pepper, ketchup
2)    2       burger, spinach, tomato
3)    3       chicken, barbecue, ham 
4)    4       onions, pepper, chicken
5)    5       book, pencil, paper
```

My goal is to return any row that has ALMOST identical to "`chicken, pepper, onions`"

I have tried the LIKE function, but it will only return rows only when the value that you provide is in correct order and can be found somewhere on the columns.

My code is like this:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE food LIKE ="%chicken, pepper, onions%"

Comment: You could make an array out of your `food` column and run a comparison of your imput against those from your array. Other option would be to use distance-based comparison algorithms such as Levenstein.

Comment: The thing is, I have hundreds of food column, and you don't want to store all of it

Comment: I'm sorry, but what's the problem actually? It seems to differ from the one you've described, as I can see you have one food column in your example schema.

Comment: If I used this code SELECT * FROM table WHERE food LIKE ="%chicken, pepper, onions%" do you think it would return anything? That's the problem

Comment: I've already told you how to address this problem. Store your string in array and compare your input against every array element (procedural) OR use a distance-based algorithm on your string column.

Comment: I have thousands and thousands of food coloumns and you DON'T WANT to store all of it and start comparing, it will slow down the performance

Comment: You're probably misunderstaning the meaning of a `column`. What you mean is that you have many `rows` which contain `food` column. Again, solutions above don't require you to change your storage manner.

Comment: If  you normalize the ingredients table. i.e. have one ingredient per row then you could join to your list of required ingredients and count the matching groups? maybe interesting? [code to generate normalize table from delimited list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33806675/3184785)