# PHP/MySQL - Find in row when there is exact occurence

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL column `Sizes` which contains on every row data looking like this:

```
6 (39), 7 (40.5), 10 (44), 11 (45), 11½ (45.5), 12 (46)
6 (39), 7, 7 (40.5), 8 (42), 8½ (42.5), 9 (43), 10 (44.5), 11 (46)
6 (39), 7, 7 (40.5), 8 (42), 8½ (42.5), 9 (43), 11 (46)
```

I want to select from MySQL only the rows which contains specificly this `7,`.

So if i have only three rows with data with the MySQL selection i have to get only the last two rows because they have `7,` which is different from `7 (45),`

Here is what i tried so far but somehow it is not working:

```
$Size = "7";
$Sizes = "$Size,";
$CategoryFilter = $_POST['CategoryFilter'];

$r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `Category`='$CategoryFilter' AND `Sizes`  LIKE '%$Sizes%'");
$SDProductCode = array();
$Number = 0;
while($rowi = mysql_fetch_array($r))
        {
        $SDProductCode[] = $rowi['ProductCode'];
        $result['productcode'][] = $rowi['ProductCode'];
        $Number++;
        }
```

Why my selection is not working, can you help me out ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: normalize the data, problem solved

Comment: maybe interesting, if you want to `normalize` the table then [joining on ';' separated values in a column](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33806675/3184785)

Answer (score 0):

Having white spaces around the commas, but still, with a bit of manipulation, [`find_in_set`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM   `products` 
WHERE  `Category` = '$CategoryFilter' AND 
       FIND_IN_SET(REPLACE('$Sizes', ' ', ''), REPLACE(`Sizes`, ' ', '')) > 0
```

**Note:** 
This should work if you're searching for `'7'`, not '7,'. I'm guessing that using the comma there was a workaround in the first place, so this may be acceptable.