# How to split a string into multiple rows based on the delimiter in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, split, delimiter

I am new to MYSQL. I have a requirement to split a string into rows based on the delimiter given by the user. User might give any delimiter and any number of times.

**For Ex:**

**Input:**

```
'ABC,DEF;GHI@JKL-MNO/PQR&STU)VWX?YZ'
```

**Output:**

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
PQR
STU
VWX
YZ
```

**Note:** I am able to do the same requirement in SQL Server. But I am not able to convert the same to MYSQL Code. If anyone can convert it to mysql, please let me know I will share the code.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us your `sql server` code

Comment: Please find the code snippet here: 

http://madprops.org/blog/splitting-text-into-words-in-sql-revisited/

It is working fine for my requirement. But I could not get the equivalent functions for CHARINDEX AND PATINDEX in MYSQL.

Comment: Here is `CharIndex` equivalent in MySQL:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr

Comment: there are a couple of functions in the code (`COUNT_IN_SET` and `VALUE_IN_SET`) that may be be useful? maybe interesting? :  Example code: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f279/1). The question: [Can I resolve this with pure mysql? (joining on ';' separated values in a column)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33806675/3184785)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I resolve this with pure mysql? (joining on ';' separated values in a column)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782728/can-i-resolve-this-with-pure-mysql-joining-on-separated-values-in-a-column)