# How to find the difference between two numbers in a comma separated array?

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a MySQL table which has two rows and two columns.

```
Column 1 = ID
Column 2 = NUMBERS
```

`NUMBERS` field in first row & second row has following comma separated value:

```
NUMBERS(Row 1) = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
NUMBERS(Row 2) = 6,7,8,9,10,11
```

Now I need to find all the numbers which are between 1 & 11. I have tried MYSQL `BETWEEN` function but it has not returned desired results.

Is there a way I can get desired result?

Comment: Go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835155/mysql-split-comma-separated-string-into-temp-table)

Since Mysql is not bundled with Split string function you have to do it on your own. Once you have splitted the number then use BETWEEN clause to fetch the desired result from temp table created in above link of example

Comment: One way: Showing all the calculations: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfea18/6. Explanation: [Can I resolve this with pure mysql? (joining on ';' separated values in a column)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33806675/3184785)

Comment: Now you know that you can't use a relational database as a text file, don't you? You create rows in SQL, you don't separate data using commas, this isn't javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Having a table with sequence numbers like

Table `sequence_numbers`

```sql
number
     1
     2
    ..
   100
```

you can extract the numbers from your list using a JOIN and FIND_IN_SET() function:

```sql
select t.ID, s.number
from mytable t
join sequence_numbers s
  on find_in_set(s.number, t.NUMBERS)
```

Result:

```sql
| ID | number |
|----|--------|
|  1 |      1 |
|  1 |      2 |
|  1 |      3 |
|  1 |      4 |
|  1 |      5 |
|  1 |      6 |
|  2 |      6 |
|  1 |      7 |
|  2 |      7 |
|  1 |      8 |
|  2 |      8 |
|  2 |      9 |
|  2 |     10 |
|  2 |     11 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4144/4

Now many tasks are much simpler with that result.

Limit to numbers from 3 to 7:

```sql
select t.ID, s.number
from mytable t
join sequence_numbers s 
  on find_in_set(s.number, t.NUMBERS)
where s.number between 3 and 7
```

Result:

```sql
| ID | number |
|----|--------|
|  1 |      3 |
|  1 |      4 |
|  1 |      5 |
|  1 |      6 |
|  2 |      6 |
|  1 |      7 |
|  2 |      7 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4144/3

A simple way to create a big sequence table is to use the internal `columns` table (or any table with enough rows) joining it with itself:

```sql
create table sequence_numbers (number int auto_increment primary key)
  select null as number
  from information_schema.columns c1
  cross join information_schema.columns c2
  limit 1000000
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cc0a/2