# MYSQL: Is it possible to concatenation multiple rows of record into one row

Tags: mysql

I want to know if there is any option to output multiple rows into a single row.

for example the regular `select * from tbl_name` will give a list of all records available in the table.

```
firstname    lastname
----------   ------------
Lepanto      Fernando
Lourdes      Brillianto
Gerald       Siluvai
```

Preferred output

firstname will have -> Lepanto###Lourdes###Gerald

lastname will have -> Fernando###Brillianto###Siluvai

Can we have some concatenation done to achieve the above.

Comment: Search for group_concat() or use any of the questions on the right hand side of your browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select group_concat(firstname separator '###') as firstnames,
       group_concat(lastname separator '###') as lastnames
from your_table
```

Comment: That did work. what a shame that i didn't knew that was possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(firstname SEPARATOR "###") as firstname,
       GROUP_CONCAT(lastname SEPARATOR "###") as lastname
from tblname
```