# SQL: how do i find customer orders with customers?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
1. `customer`
2. `customer_order`

Customer table contains customer data(duh) and customer_order contains all the orders.
I can join them on `customer.id=customer_order.id_customer`.

All fine, but now i want a query, where i have all the customer ids, and next the orders(customer_order.id) which these customers made (with order date)

like this:

```
customer 100    order 4, order 5, order 9
customer 101    order 7, order 8, order 15
```

I have this, but doesn't give me the result, it puts all the customer ids with an order on different rows:

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstname, co.id
FROM customer c
JOIN customer_order co
ON c.id=co.id_customer
;
```

Comment: Not group by - `order by c.id, c.firstname`

Comment: How do you want the date to be displayed? Your example output doesn't show that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level/presentation layer if you have one (e.g. with a bit of PHP)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the group_concat function

```
select c.id, c.firstname, GROUP_CONCAT(co.id SEPARATOR ',')
from custom c
join custom_order co
group by c.id
```

this would return something like

```
customer 100 | 4,5,9
customer 101 | 7,8,15
```

Comment: I got this result:                                                    Query : select c.id, c.firstname, GROUP_CONCAT(co.id SEPARATOR ',')  from customer c  join customer_order co  group by c.id LIMIT 0, 100...
Error Code : 126
Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_42a_0.MYI'; try to repair it
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstname, co.id
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN customer_order co
ON c.id=co.id_customer
ORDER BY c.id;
```

It's either LEFT or INNER, you'll get different results depending on which you use, and I think for your purposes LEFT is the one you want to use. Then when you retrieve the data, you might have to drop it into:

```
array["custid"][] = co.id
```