# Joining table data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table of:

```
id   title     type   expl   bubble_content   onfocus   req   dorder   label    mirror
1    Fullname  1      1      Your fullname    Yes       0     0        0        NULL
```

Then another table of:

```
id     fieldid    relid    dorder
4      1          2        0
5      1          1        0
```

How would I join the two tables so that the result would be something like:

```
0 => array(
     'id' => 1,
     'title' => 'Fullname',
     .... etc ....
     'relid' => 2,
     'relid' => 1),
1 => array(
     .... etc ....
))
```

I've tried using INNER JOIN / LEFT JOIN but this produces two rows/arrays for each relid, **I would really like all the data for the particular fieldid to exist within the same array**, as illustrated above.

Comment: You can't have an array with two identical keys, that makes no sense.

Comment: How are you joining the tables?  Where do the values 1 and 2 come from?

Comment: @JakubKania Obviously. I'm asking if there is no way to join them using SQL

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have 2 keys with the same name in an array. On your example you have 2 'relid', the second one will overwrite the first.

You can code PHP so that it merges those rows into one:

```
    $output = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        // Capture all values for this row first.
        // If this is the new row from the first table, store.
        if (!isset($output[$row['id']]))
        {
            $output[$row['id']] = $row;

            // Make a new array for relids.
            $output[$row['id']]['relids'] = array();
        }


        $output[$row['id']]['relids'][] = $row['relid']; 

    }
```

Your output array will look like this:

```
0 => array(
 'id' => 1,
 'title' => 'Fullname',
 .... etc ....
 'relids' => array(2, 1),
1 => array(
 .... etc ....
))
```