# Set Mysql-Parameter group_concat_max_len

Tags: mysql, jpa

I'm using JPA / EclipseLink for Database-Access. Within my MySQL-Database I need to seet the Parameter group_concat_max_len to a larger number. Can I do this with JPA?

I tried it with the following statement:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SET  group_concat_max_len = 10240;");
```

But this throws an java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid call on a query that does not return result sets.

Can somebody help?

Thanks
Bernhard

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field/276949#276949

Answer (score 0):

Line of code that causes error is missing from the question. Following does not throw described exception:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SET  group_concat_max_len = 10240;");
```

But if created instance of Query is used as follows, then exception will be thrown:

```
query.getResultList();
//or 
query.getSingleResult();
```

Solution is to call [executeUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate%28%29) method instead of ones above:

```
query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, now after embedding the executeUpdate in a transaction, it worked.