# How to update a row without delete current value in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization, sql-update

One of my table has a field `tags` and the value of the field like {2,3,8}

```
tag_id  | r_tags  
--------|------------   
1       | {2,3,8}  
--------|------------  
2       | {5,8}
```

I want to update the field without deleting the current value. For ex. If I need to add `5` for tag id `1`, then {2,3,8} should be like {2,3,8,5}

Now its works like

```
 1. Select the current value.
 2. Add 5 using php and created new string.
 3. Update the row.
```

I just want to know is it possible only through MySql?

Comment: Google for "many to many"

Comment: how you are inserting this value..can you share that code?

Comment: You can use MySQL `CONCAT()`

Comment: @Jenz now i create the string using PHP, then update the value using simple update query like update table set r_tags='{2,3,8,5}' where tag_id='1'.

Comment: UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, '}', concat(',', new_value, '}')
WHERE your_field = ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work - 
Assuming you want to add 5 in `r_tags` in `tag_id = 1`, this should be the query -

```
UPDATE tags SET r_tags = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(r_tags, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(r_tags) - 1),',5','}') WHERE tag_id = 1;
```

In php,

```
// $new_val and $tag_id as variables.
$query = "UPDATE tags SET r_tags = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(r_tags, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(r_tags) - 1),',$new_val','}') WHERE tag_id = $tag_id"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE your_table SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, '}', concat(',', new_value, '}') WHERE your_field = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query for Mysql and you can replace any value with '5' whatever you want to add.

```
Update tbl_tags SET r_tags = INSERT(r_tags, INSTR(r_tags, '}'), 1, CONCAT(',','5','}')) WHERE tag_id = '1'
```