# Mysql query to concat rows

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

Mysql tables structure is

**B1**      //table 1

```
aid         name     
1            aaa
2            bbb
3            ccc
4            ddd
```

**B2**      //table 2

```
bid         aid
111          1
222          2
333          3
444          3
555          4
```

I want to display data like following

```
aid      bid             name
1        111              aaa
2        222              bbb
3        333,444          ccc
4        555              ddd
```

I tried to do but not getting result as expected.
How to do this using subquery or joins?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Comment: I saw that but that was from single table. I want to do by using 2 tables

Comment: Are you familiar with join if not first read joins and then try to map the dup solution on your query

Comment: Eh? Your query only requires one table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group_concat

```
SELECT
    B1.aid,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B2.bid) bids,
    B1.name
FROM B1
LEFT JOIN B2 ON B1.aid = B2.aid
GROUP BY B1.aid
```

### Fiddle Demo

Output

```
| AID |    BIDS | NAME |
|-----|---------|------|
|   1 |     111 |  aaa |
|   2 |     222 |  bbb |
|   3 | 333,444 |  ccc |
|   4 |     555 |  ddd |
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what i have tried to describe in comments,you can use [*group-concat*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

### Join approach

```
select t.aid,group_concat(t2.bid) bid
from t
join t2 using(aid)
group by t.aid
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fe537/3)

### Single table approach

```
select t2.aid,group_concat(t2.bid) bid
from t2
group by t2.aid
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fe537/4)

> Beware of that fact it has a default limit of characters to concat as per docs *The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024.The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet*

Comment: I don't think "single table approach" is addressing the issue OP had and it should be obious from the "join" example you have. It might also be worthwhile to consider `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.bid)` even though it isn't clear whether OP needs that.

Comment: @vhu I have posted answer for the [**previous version of question**](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24119890/1) if you see the edits of question and first sample dataset it doesn't have a name column in first table