# mysql get different rows as one row different column

Tags: mysql, database

Let say I have the following tables

```
Applications
- id
- studentid
- company_id
-status

Company
-company_id
-company_name

Student
-studentid
-studentname
```

Now let say a student apply 3 companies

So I would like the result to be displayed like this.the result will only be one row.

```
Id | student name | company 1 | company 2 | company 3
```

Can I know how to make like the above. I manage to do the multiple row using join statement. But how to do like the one I exactly want.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Comment: That's called "denormalize".

Comment: Mike w.. group_concat is among the thing I get by searching through google. But how to display it in different column.. I dont want it to be displayed as a string..