# Selecting data as a single row when using select join in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I get data from a mysql query in a single row when selecting data from two tables using a join?

```
"id"    "itemId"    "itemTempId"    "itemName"                  "userId" "postId"
"1"     "US1"       "T001"          "Samsung Galaxy Note 5"     "1"      "1"

"id"    "itemId"    "itemTempId"    "itemImageName"     "userId" "postId"
"1"     "US1"       "T001"          "front.jpg"         "1"      "1"
"2"     "US1"       "T001"          "side-left.jpg"     "1"      "1"
"3"     "US1"       "T001"          "side-right.jpg"    "1"      "1"
"4"     "US1"       "T001"          "back.jpg"          "1"      "1"
```

Right now, when I do like below to select 1 row from the first table and related rows from the second table, I get all data in every row which also repeats when I print it using php.

```
select a.itemName, b.itemImageName from amga a left join amgb b on a.userId = b.userId where a.userId = 1;
```

**Current Output**

```
"itemName"                  "itemImageName"
"Samsung Galaxy Note 5"     "front.jpg"
"Samsung Galaxy Note 5"     "side-left.jpg"
"Samsung Galaxy Note 5"     "side-right.jpg"
"Samsung Galaxy Note 5"     "back.jpg"
```

**Desirable Output** or some other variation that wont repeat the itemName and that can easily be output using php.

```
"itemName"                  "itemImageName"
"Samsung Galaxy Note 5"     "front.jpg","side-left.jpg","side-right.jpg","back.jpg"
```

In the final results the title is output only once, whereas the image names need to be looped through. Like this:

```
"Samsung Galaxy Note 5"
"front.jpg","side-left.jpg","side-right.jpg","back.jpg"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need grouping with the `GROUP_CONCAT` function. Please try this query:

```
select a.itemName, group_concat(b.itemImageName) 
from amga a left join amgb b on a.userId = b.userId 
where a.userId = 1 
group by a.itemName;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.itemName, GROUP_CONCAT(b.itemImageName) 
from amga a 
left join amgb b 
on a.userId = b.userId 
where a.userId = 1
group by a.itemName
```

Use DISTINCT into GROUP_CONCAT if you dont want duplicates.

Comment: In your statement, is it possible to use a `limit 1` on the `itemImageName` column so I get only 1 image when I need to output only one image, like for search results etc?

Comment: @Norman  You could use SUBSTRING_INDEX on GROUP_CONCAT results to get one result Here is a random fiddle example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb704/6 selecting the secound largest value from each group.

Answer (score 2):

The [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) operator is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT    item_name, GROUP_CONCAT(item_image_name)
FROM      amga
LEFT JOIN amgb ON amga.userId = b.userId
WHERE     amge.userId = 1
GROUP BY  item_name
```

Comment: In your statement, is it possible to use a `limit 1` on the `itemImageName` column so I get only 1 image when I need to output only one image, like for search results etc?

Comment: @Norman you'd have to replace `amgb` with a subquery, and use `limit` there. Otherwise, the `limit` will be applied to the complete query, which isn't what you want.