# Reasons not to use GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just discovered this amazingly useful MySQL function `GROUP_CONCAT`. It appears so useful and over-simplifying for me that I'm actually afraid of using it. Mainly because it's been quite some time since I started in web-programming and I've never seen it anywhere. A sample of awesome usage would be the following

Table `clients` holds clients ( you don't say... ) one row per client with unique IDs.
Table `currencies` has 3 columns `client_id`, `currency` and `amount`.

Now if I wanted to get user 15's `name` from the `clients` table and his balances, with the "old" method of array overwriting I would have to do use the following SQL

```
SELECT id, name, currency, amount 
FROM clients LEFT JOIN currencies ON clients.id = client_id 
WHERE clients.id = 15
```

Then in php I would have to loop through the result set and do an array overwrite ( which I'm really not a big fan of, especially in massive result sets ) like

```
$result = array();
foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row){
    $result[$row['id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
    $result[$row['id']]['currencies'][$row['currency']] = $row['amount'];
}
```

However with the newly discovered function I can use this

```
SELECT id, name, GROUP_CONCAT(currency) as currencies GROUP_CONCAT(amount) as amounts 
FROM clients LEFT JOIN currencies ON clients.id = client_id 
WHERE clients.id = 15
GROUP BY clients.id
```

Then on application level things are so awesome and pretty

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($results as $k => $v){
    $results[$k]['currencies'] = array_combine(explode(',', $v['currencies']), explode(',', $v['amounts']));
}
```

The question I would like to ask is are there any drawbacks to using this function in performance or anything at all, because to me it just looks like pure awesomeness, which makes me think that there must be a reason for people not to be using it quite often.

## EDIT:

I want to ask, eventually, what are the other options besides array overwriting to end up with a multidimensional array from a MySQL result set, because if I'm selecting 15 columns it's a really big pain in the neck to write that beast..

Comment: it's handy, but it's not universally handy. It DOES have a limited length on the string it can return, usually 1024 chars by default. If you have a 'large' data set, your concatted string can easily exceed 1024 chars and it WILL be silently truncated/corrupted.

Comment: It's all covered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field/276949#276949

Comment: that length can be configured

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Using GROUP_CONCAT() usually invokes the group-by logic and creates temporary tables, which are usually a big negative for performance. Sometimes you can add the right index to avoid the temp table in a group-by query, but not in every case.
- As @MarcB points out, the default length limit of a group-concatenated string is pretty short, and many people have been confused by truncated lists. You can increase the limit with [group_concat_max_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).
- Exploding a string into an array in PHP does not come for free. Just because you can do it in one function call in PHP doesn't mean it's the best for performance. I haven't benchmarked the difference, but I doubt you have either.
- GROUP_CONCAT() is a MySQLism. It is not supported widely by other SQL products. In some cases (e.g. SQLite), they have a GROUP_CONCAT() function, but it doesn't work exactly the same as in MySQL, so this can lead to confusing bugs if you have to support multiple RDBMS back-ends. Of course, if you don't need to worry about porting, this is not an issue.
- If you want to fetch multiple columns from your `currencies` table, then you need multiple GROUP_CONCAT() expressions. Are the lists guaranteed to be in the same order? That is, does the third field in one list correspond to the third field in the next list? The answer is no -- not unless you specify the order with an `ORDER BY` clause inside the GROUP_CONCAT().

I usually favor your first code format, use a conventional result set, and loop over the results, saving to a new array indexed by client id, appending the currencies to an array. This is a straightforward solution, keeps the SQL simple and easier to optimize, and works better if you have multiple columns to fetch.

I'm not trying to say GROUP_CONCAT() is bad! It's really useful in many cases. But trying to make any one-size-fits-all rule to use (or to avoid) any function or language feature is simplistic.

Comment: What I miss in this answer is an explanation why there's never a good reason to even need group_concat in the first place.

Comment: @popovitsj array overwriting with large result sets and large number of selected columns is inefficient and a pain to code, is this not a good reason? ( Not saying that group_concat is more efficient, just thinking )

Comment: @popovitsj, see my answer to https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/90456/why-dont-relational-databases-support-returning-information-in-a-nested-format, including the discussion in the comments.

Comment: @php_nub_qq, I'd test it on a case-by-case basis. As you say, the number of rows fetched in either table can affect which solution is more efficient. Don't guess, test!

Comment: @php_nub_qq I don't get why you think you need this array overwrite, but of course, I don't know anything else about your application. I like to believe that the reason you don't see group_concat() very often is because it goes against a core principle of Relational Databases and I think that the need for this function is mostly fueled by people who don't really 'get' Relational databases.

Comment: @popovitsj I'm just asking in general. Because when I join 2 or more tables most of the cases I will end up with a result set containing many identical rows with X number of columns that differentiate. In PHP this would be represented as a multidimensional array and the question is basically how to easily and efficiently convert this 2d result set to a php object ( multidimensional array )

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem that I see with `GROUP_CONCAT` is that it is highly specific to MySql: if you want to port your code to run against any other platform, you would have to rewrite all queries that use `GROUP_CONCAT`. For example, your first query is a lot more portable - you can probably run it against any major RDBMS engine without changing a single character in it.

If you are fine with working only with MySql (say, because you are writing a tool that is meant to be specific to MySql) the queries with `GROUP_CONCAT` would probably go faster, because the RDBMS would do more work for you, saving on the size of the data transfer.

Comment: Port my code? Man my code wont work if my room temperature changes! lol `:D`