# group by and group_concat alternative

Tags: php, mysql

*Using `GROUP_CONCAT()` usually invokes the group-by logic and creates temporary tables, which are usually a big negative for performance. Sometimes you can add the right index to avoid the temp table in a group-by query, but not in every case.*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26225148/9685125

After Reading this post, I realized that I was doing wrong, because many time I made complicated query using huge `GROUP_CONCAT()`. Such as

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT exam.title) AS exam,
GROUP_CONCAT(subject.title, '<br/> Th - ', mark.th, ' | PR - ', mark.pr SEPARATOR ',') AS mark
```

But what can be alternative of `GROUP_CONCAT` in following situation without using `subquery`. I mean using only `Mysql join`,

For example, let see two relational database and and query to explain my problem

**Student**

```
id  |   Rid |   name
========================
1   |   1   |   john
```

**Marks**

```
id  |   std_id  |   th
======================
1   |   1       |   60
2   |   1       |   70
3   |   1       |   80
4   |   1       |   90

"SELECT 
    student.en_name, mark.th 
    FROM student
    JOIN mark ON student.id = mark.std_id
    WHERE student.id=:id;"
```

Column would be repeated if only use `JOIN`

```
John: 60, John: 70, John: 80, John: 90
```

So, I use `GROUP BY`. But if I assign `GROUP BY` to student.id, only first row is fetched

```
"SELECT 
    student.en_name, mark.th 
    FROM student
    JOIN mark ON student.id = mark.std_id
    WHERE student.id=:id
    GROUP BY student.id;"

Result is
John: 60
```

So to get result, we have to assign that `group.concat`

```
"SELECT 
    student.en_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(mark.th) as mark 
    FROM student
    JOIN mark ON student.id = mark.std_id
    WHERE student.id=:id
    GROUP BY student.id;"
```

And final and expected result using exploding array

```
$name=$row['en_name'];
echo "$name: <br/>";
$mrk_array = explode(',',$row['mark']); 
foreach($mrk_array as $mark){
    echo $mark.", ";
}

John:
60, 70, 80, 90,
```

Here, I don't see any alternative of `GROUP_CONCAT` to fetch all associated value of each `Id` and prevent duplicate, please help me how to replace `GROUP_CONCAT` from here.

Also, one friend told me

**So why `GROUP_CONCAT` if you're "exploding" it. You might as well return a nice associative array and then deal with displaying it there.**

But I can't understand, what he means ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment...

With your original query, you are effectively returning an array of rows (associative arrays):

```
array(array('en_name' => 'John', 'mark' => 60),
      array('en_name' => 'John', 'mark' => 70),
      array('en_name' => 'John', 'mark' => 80),
      array('en_name' => 'John', 'mark' => 90)
     )
```

When you use `GROUP BY` and `GROUP CONCAT`, you are effectively `imploding` the `'mark'` elements of that array to

```
array('en_name => 'John', 'mark' => '60,70,80,90')
```

and you then have to `explode` the array again to process the data.

If you stick with your original query, you can instead do the imploding in your application framework e.g.

```
$name = "";
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    if ($row['en_name'] != $name) {
        $name = $row['en_name'];
        echo "$name: <br/>" . $row['mark'];
    }
    else {
        echo ',' . $row['mark'];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
John: 
60,70,80,90
```

This will generally be a lot faster than using `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` in the database.