# mysql join repeats row, order by caused problem

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch each class name, students in this class and subjects assigned to this class.

Here, Problem is caused by `ORDER BY`, I have assigned `ORDER BY` to `student.id`.

This causes **subject rows duplication**.

If `ORDER BY` is not assign, **subject rows are fetched** as expected, are not duplicate, but **student row duplicates**.

**Table structure**

**Student**

```
id  |   Rid |   class   |   name
================================
1   |   1   |   1       |   John
2   |   2   |   1       |   Harsita
```

**Class**

```
id  |   title
==============
1   |   One
2   |   two
3   |   three
```

**Subject**

```
id  |   title
===============
1   |   science
2   |   math
3   |   english
4   |   social
5   |   hpe
```

**class_subject**

```
id  |   class   |   subject
===========================
1   |   1       |   1   
2   |   1       |   2
3   |   1       |   3
4   |   1       |   4
```

**Requirement is**

```
class: One
Science | Math | English | Social | Hpe | 
John | Harsita
```

**But what I get**

if `ORDER BY` is assigned to `student.id`

```
class: One
Science | Math | English | Social | Hpe | Math | English | Social | Hpe | Science | 
John | Harsita |
```

if `ORDER BY` has not assigned to `student.id`

```
class: One
Science | Math | English | Social | Hpe | 
John | Harsita | John | Harsita | John | Harsita | John | Harsita | John | Harsita |
```

I've tried using `GROUP BY` to `subject.id`, it displays only one student (first row: John). Where is problem ? How can I solve without using `subquery` or `GROUP_CONCAT`

**code - php and mysql (with ORDER BY)**

```
//mysql query
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT class_subject.class, 
        subject.title AS sub,
        student.name AS stdt,
        class.title AS class
    FROM 
        student
    INNER JOIN class_subject ON class_subject.class=student.class
    INNER JOIN subject ON subject.id=class_subject.subject
    INNER JOIN class ON class.id=student.class
    WHERE
        student.class=:cid;

//php
    $class='';
    $stdt='';
    $sub='';
    $results = Array();
        while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            if ($row['class'] != $class){
                $class = $row['class'];
                echo "Class: ".$class."<br/>";
            }
            if ($row['sub'] != $sub){
                $sub = $row['sub'];
                echo $sub." | ";
            }
            $results[]=$row;
        }
        echo "<br/>";
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            if ($row['stdt'] != $stdt) {
                $stdt = $row['stdt'];
                echo $stdt." | ";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking to your expected  result sampel seem that you need  an aggregated  result  for name and subject

```
SELECT 
    group_concat( subject.title) AS sub,
    group_concat(student.name) AS stdt,
    class.title AS class
FROM 
    student
INNER JOIN class_subject ON class_subject.class=student.class
INNER JOIN subject ON subject.id=class_subject.subject
INNER JOIN class ON class.id=student.class
WHERE student.class=:cid
group by class.title
```

using aggreation function and group you can show the aggregated  result on the same row

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is it possible to fetch expected result without using `GROUP_CONCAT`?  I want to avoid `GROUP_CONCAT`. So I have used the word **without** `GROUP_CONCAT` in question.

Comment: if you want the query result on the same rows  you must use an aggregated  function as  group_concat and group by ... otherwise you can perform the same query you have used in your questiion  and format the result using php .. building the string you need  for output ..

Comment: anyway .. why you don't want group by and group concat ?  ..  do the fact you are selecting few  rows  filter by :cid .. and you have proper index  of joi  involved  column you can't have performance problem..

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` invokes the group-by logic and creates temporary tables, which can be a big negative for performance. After reading this post - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225069/reasons-not-to-use-group-concat], I am trying to avoid, if possible.

Comment: well what 's  your performance requirements  ..?   .. how many rows  are involved  by each table?  ..how many rows in average are involved  by each cid..?   if you have billions  of  rows  involved  and for these billions of rows  involved  you need  response  for some decimal seconds  then    your performance  your worries  have sense .. otherwise  .. not ..  .. you should try executing the query  .in a sql console or sql IDE and check for your real  timing results ... you should read  the answer  in question but related  to the real question  .. and not simpy transpose the  answer t

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by all the `JOIN`s. There are 4 subjects associated with class 1, and 2 students. So you will get 4*2 = 8 rows in your result. As you have seen, the result of the join will be either 2 sets of the 4 subject names, or 4 sets of the 2 student names. You can choose to deal with this in your PHP code, or since you are effectively grouping in the PHP code anyway, do the grouping in your query:

```
SELECT 
    c.title AS class,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.title ORDER BY s.title SEPARATOR ' | ') AS subjects,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.name ORDER BY t.name SEPARATOR ' | ') AS students
FROM class c
JOIN class_subject cs ON cs.class=c.id
JOIN subject s ON s.id=cs.subject
JOIN student t ON c.id=t.class
WHERE c.id=1
GROUP BY class
```

Output:

```
class   subjects                            students
One     english | math | science | social   Harsita | John
```

Note that you can specify an `ORDER BY` inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` to control the ordering of the values in the group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to know, is it possible without using `GROUP_CONCAT`. So I have used the word **without** `GROUP_CONCAT` in question.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part of the question.Without `GROUP_CONCAT` you will end up with 8 rows of data for the sample data in your question, and you will have to process that in your PHP code. And it will get worse as you add more subjects and students to each class. The only other alternative would be 2 queries, one to select all subjects associated with a class, and the other to select all students associated with a class.

Comment: that's the point, I think for performance 2 queries would be better than `GROUP_CONCAT`, isn't it ? because`GROUP_CONCAT()`  invokes the group-by logic and creates temporary tables, which can be a big negative for performance, isn't it ?

Comment: I don't think `GROUP_CONCAT` necessarily causes that big a performance impact. But it's probably one of those things where you need to benchmark it in your own environment. However given how easy it is for you to achieve what you want with 2 simple queries, that probably would be faster.