# How to store variable number of languages per user?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a standard user table. Now each user can add an unknown number of languages to his profile. What is the best way of storing the languages for each user? I want to query only **once** to fetch a user and all his corresponding languages. What is the best design?

Example:

```
User
====

id    name    
----------
99    peter


Languages
=========

id    userid    lang
-------------------- 
44    99        en
45    99        fr
```

Comment: You need a third table for the relationship between users and languages `new_table(uderid,languageid)` and keep `languages(id,lang)`

Comment: users and language table can be related with `id` and `userid` column in above design, no need of third table. I think it is good.

Comment: Yes I will do that, but thats not the point I am asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a many to many relationship (a user can have many languages, and viceversa) so to normalize the DB you should do a new table containing the two Foreign Keys (call it user_x_languages):

```
user_x_languages
================
user_id    lang_id
99         44
99         45
```

you would need to remove the userid column from you languages table

the query should then use a join

```
select name lang from user u
join user_x_languages x on u.id = x.user_id
join languages l on x.lang_id = l.id
where u.id = 99;
```

that would output a row for each language the user has, it will however be repeating the username on each row.

You want to look into DB normalization, a very nice non-technical article is this: [A Simple Guide to Five Normal Forms in Relational Database Theory](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm)

following the advice of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field) thread about returning one line, the procedure would be something like (I might have changed the table and column names a little bit from your original):

```
delimiter //

Create function languages (p_user varchar(30))
returns text
begin
    DECLARE ret_val TEXT;
    select GROUP_CONCAT(lang) into ret_val
    from Users u
    join user_x_lang x on u.user_id = x.user_id
    join Lang l on x.lang_id = l.lang_id
    where u.name = p_user;
    return ret_val;
end//

delimiter ;
```

and now the select should be (for all users):

```
select name, languages(name) from users;
```

Comment: Thanks, so what is best practice to query a user and all his languages then? Repeating the username etc does not seem to be best?

Comment: Since you're querying with a specific username you can omit the name in the select statement.
In the case of multiple users you can use a function to query the DB for each user, which will return them as text

Comment: Yes but I will have other columns of the user like email, photo etc. I want all user data ONCE and the languages added

Comment: I've edited and added the function, follow the link to the question on GROUP_CONCAT(), to see the limit it has, you might have to change it if your table starts having many languages per user.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a many-to-many relationship table. Like this:

Table "Users"

```
user_id | name
99        peter
100       tim
```

Table "Languages"

```
language_id | language
44            en
45            fr
```

Table "User_to_language"

```
User_id | Language_id
99        45
100       45
100       46
```

Or, if you need a lot of user attributes in future, you might use something like:
Table User_attributes

```
user_id | attribute | value
46        'lang'      'en'
```

Also, this might be useful for you: [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: can you write a query to get the user data from Users joining his languages?

Comment: select u.name, l.language
  from Users u
  join User_to_language utl
    on utl.User_id = u.User_id 
  join Languages l
    on l.Language_id = utl.Language_id
 where u.name = 'tim';

Comment: this will also return a table with each language - correct - however on each row the user data is also added. Is that best practice?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the best practice, but I saw it multiple times in enterprise level projects. A table like I mentioned is going to be really small even with billion rows in it, so I can no doubt say that it will be good in terms of performance. At least for most OLTP systems.

Answer (score 1):

Normalization is used to save the disk space i.e. a good normalized database takes lesser space than non-normalized but the price you pay is performance. Keep in mind more normalization = more join = more processing overhead. **In my opinion**, your design (using two tables) is good, you can easily retrieve data with a single join :

```
select * from Usrs u join Languages l on u.id = l.usrid

now some sample queries which will come in application code 
--select those users who speak 'en' then 

select * from Usrs u join Languages l on u.id = l.usrid
where l.lang = 'en'

--peter speaks which languages 
select * from Usrs u join Languages l on u.id = l.usrid
where u.name = 'peter'
```

try the same with a normalized data base you will find that you need all three tables to get desired data.