# How to concatenate multiple rows into one field in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Using simple query , I can do something like

```
SELECT hobbies FROM peoples_hobbies WHERE person_id = 5;
```

and get:

```
shopping

fishing  

coding
```

but instead I just want 1 row, 1 col:

```
shopping, fishing, coding
```

for ref-- [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

I want to do this in sql server ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have great support for aggregate string concatenation.  But you can do:

```
select stuff((select ', ' + hobbies
              from peoples_hobbies
              where person_id = 5
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 2, '') as hobbies;
```