# Update a column of multiple rows of a table using joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

**EDIT**

I tried this query but got an error:

```
UPDATE consultation_med
SET consultation_med.given_quantity = 0
FROM
consultation_med
left join consultation on consultation.consultation_id = consultation_med.consultation_id
left join visit on visit.visit_id = consultation.visit_id
 WHERE visit.visit_id='191'
           AND consultation_med.given_quantity = '361'
```

the error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FROM consultation_med left join consultation on
>   consultation.consultation_id = c' at line 3

**END EDIT**

I need to update a table called `consultation_med` and change the `given_quantity` of a medication into `0` when the status of a visit `visit_status` is changed from `Active` to `Inactive`.

Please take note that in the visit table, each `visit_id` can have multiple `consultation_id` in the next table which is `consultation`. And in each `consultation_id` doctors can give multiple medication with different quantities so we have now for each `consultation_id` multiple rows in `consultation_med` table.

Here are the tables:

[image]

So let's take the `visit_id=173` that already had 4 consultation_id and in each consultation doctors prescribed 1 medication. So we have 4 rows related to visit where `visit_id=173` in `consultation_med` table. The data entry had an error and he need to send an request to the admin by changing the status of this visit to `Inactive`, so every medication quantity given should be back to inital storage, thus we should change the `given_quantity` of each 4 rows to `0`.

I tried in PHP the following query but apparently it is taking just one row and updating it:

```
$med_pharmacy_id = $res['med_pharmacy_id'];
$consultation_med_id = $res['consultation_med_id'];

$update = "UPDATE consultation_med 
SET given_quantity = 0 
WHERE med_pharmacy_id = :mid
AND clinic_id = :cid 
AND consultation_med_id = :cmid";
```

Then I tried to use left JOIN inside update query:

```
UPDATE consultation_med 
left join consultation on consultation.consultation_id = consultation_med.consultation_id
left join visit on visit.visit_id = consultation.visit_id

SET consultation_med.given_quantity = 0 
WHERE visit.visit_id='173'
AND consultation_med.given_quantity = '361'
```

The query is still wrong plus an extra error which is:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to
>   update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe
>   mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Answer (score 3):

That error "1175" you need to change in edit or setting -> preferences in your SQL editor to DISABLE SAFE MODE, or you should to use phpmyadmin.

Comment: I need to keep it, so later on user laptop can be done normally so I need to change the query

Comment: hmmm, you should also try subquery, thats good for updates, but little harder

Comment: example of code is here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45191560/sql-subquery-return-more-than-1-row

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you should write the update statement as: update-join-set-where

Something like this:

```
UPDATE consultation_med
LEFT JOIN consultation on consultation.consultation_id = consultation_med.consultation_id
LEFT JOIN visit on visit.visit_id = consultation.visit_id
SET consultation_med.given_quantity = 0
 WHERE visit.visit_id='191'
           AND consultation_med.given_quantity = '361'
```

For more details, visit [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/) link