# How to use multiple order by in a sql query with limit keyword?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get nth highest salary in a table by first limiting result set to n top salaries first and then to reverse the result set and limiting it to 1.

I have used this query which is resulting into an error:-

```
select *
  from salaries
 where emp_no=(select * from salaries order by salary desc limit 2) order by salary asc limit 1;
```

The error states that subquery return more than one row.

Comment: Tip: NEVER use `SELECT *`

Comment: Use like this "Select colname1,colname2 from salaries where emp_no=(select

Comment: seems like a complicated solution for a simple problem. say you want to get the 5th top salary, query the salary column, order it by asc limit 1 offset 4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solution to "subquery returns more than 1 row" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171474/solution-to-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL - ORDER BY & LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708708/mysql-order-by-limit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT s.* FROM 
(SELECT * FROM `salaries` ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 2) s
 ORDER BY s.salary ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Never use `SELECT *`, see http://www.parseerror.com/blog/select-*-is-evil

Comment: This isn't ugly at all

Comment: @lukasz-szozda 's answer below that I upvoted is a far more elegant solution. I was more trying to make his query work as requested.  My assumption was that there was some other reasons for using the sub-select (learning sub-selects, etc) which is why I kept it and merely implemented it correctly.  I consider unnecessary queries as ugly and focus on efficiency.   Sorry if my verbiage offended.

Comment: Potentially, they do different things

Answer (score 3):

If you want second highest value you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM salaries
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1,1;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c1833831945b753d63eed419934b5fb)**

Comment: I am upvoting because this does functionally what the OP wants and is the best solution (and is the first answer with that solution).  It should probably explain that using a subquery with two sorts is *not* the best solution in any database that supports `offset`s.

Comment: Fully agreed and upvoting your comment! My solution accomplishes the task using subqueries only because I wanted to also illustrate a proper way to use subqueries.  When in doubt always get your solution doing as few queries as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from salaries 
order by salary 
desc limit 1 offset 4;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2itHSFs2enyNpJ3MK6Nxcz/0