# Multiple row update in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

**support_table**

```
+------+-------------+
| num  | num_explain |
+------+-------------+
| 1    | 01          |
| 2    | 01          |
| 2    | 02          |
| 3    | 01          |
| 3    | 02          |
| 3    | 03          |
| 4    | 01          |
| 4    | 02          |
| 4    | 03          |
| 4    | 04          |
| 5    | 01          |
| 5    | 02          |
| 5    | 03          |
| 5    | 04          |
| 5    | 05          |
+------+-------------+
```

**class_room**

```
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| seq_no          | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name            | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| subjects        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| no_of_student   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| student_roll_no | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now I've tried the below query to insert data into table `class_room`:

```sql
INSERT INTO class_room (seq_no,name,subjects,no_of_student,student_roll_no)
SELECT '1', 'class11', 'physics', num, num_explain FROM support_table 
WHERE num='3';
```

this query works totally fine for me and it creates 3 rows. Now the table looks like below:

```
+---------+---------+----------+---------------+-----------------+
| seq_no  | name    | subjects | no_of_student | student_roll_no |
+---------+---------+----------+---------------+-----------------+
| 1       | class11 | physics  | 3             | 01              |
| 1       | class11 | physics  | 3             | 02              |
| 1       | class11 | physics  | 3             | 03              |
+---------+---------+----------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Now I want to update this table, so I've tried the below code:

```
UPDATE class_room 
SET name='class11', subjects='chemistry', no_of_student = 
         (SELECT num_explain FROM support_table WHERE num='4') 
WHERE seq_no='1';
```

But this query IS showing that

> Subquery returns more than one row.

Here I want that in `class_room` table `no_of_student` will be changed to '4' and `student_roll_no` will be upto '04' and instead of 3 rows, 4 rows will be created.

Comment: You are asking to update one row at a time by changing the values of `name`, `subjects` and `no_of_student`... but the catch here is that you are asking *at the same time* to select ***multiple*** values of `num_explain` into `no_of_student`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 rows in the table but you expect finally to get 4 rows.
This can't be done with an `UPDATE` statement which **does not add new rows**.
The simplest way to do what you want is to delete the current rows and then insert:

```
delete from class_room where no_of_student = 3;

insert into class_room (seq_no,name,subjects,no_of_student,student_roll_no) 
select '1', 'class11','chemistry',num,num_explain 
from support_table 
where num='4';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9o8eZRtvwG6GP8xhrr232L/0).

```
| seq_no | name    | subjects  | no_of_student | student_roll_no |
| ------ | ------- | --------- | ------------- | --------------- |
| 1      | class11 | chemistry | 4             | 1               |
| 1      | class11 | chemistry | 4             | 2               |
| 1      | class11 | chemistry | 4             | 3               |
| 1      | class11 | chemistry | 4             | 4               |
```

Answer (score 0):

`=` Can be used when the subquery returns only 1 value.

When subquery returns more than 1 value, you will have to use `IN` :

```
UPDATE class_room set name='class11',subjects='chemistry',no_of_student IN (select num_explain FROM support_table WHERE num='4')LIMIT 1 WHERE seq_no='1';
```

Example :

```
select * 
from table
where id IN (multiple row query);
```

Another example :

```
SELECT *
FROM Students
WHERE Marks = (SELECT MAX(Marks) FROM Students)   --A Example Subquery returning 1 value

SELECT *
FROM Students
WHERE Marks IN 
      (SELECT Marks 
       FROM Students 
       ORDER BY Marks DESC
       LIMIT 10)                       --Example Subquery returning 10 values
```

> A good explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171474/solution-to-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row-error) by @Raging bull

Comment: this doesn't look right for a SET. Maybe LIMIT 1 would work

Comment: still sub querty will return multiple and got the same rror