# Multiple group by queries in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

```
Query:
Select Manager, Sum(category1),
(select Sum(category2) from iris where month1 = "March" and Org1 = "ABC" group by Manager),
Sum(category1) - (select Sum(category2) from iris where month = "March" and Org1 = "ABC" group by Manager) from iris where month1 = "April" and Org1 = "ABC"
group by manager
order by manager;
```

The above query throws and error : "Subquery returns more than one row", please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solution to "subquery returns more than 1 row" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171474/solution-to-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row-error)

Answer (score 0):

You have not explained your DB structure involved in this question.

Definitely, subquery may return multiple rows for specified month and org1 columns. You may use a `LIMIT number` statement:

```
Select Manager, Sum(category1),
(select Sum(category2) from iris where month1 = "March" and Org1 = "ABC" LIMIT 1 group by Manager),
Sum(category1) - (select Sum(category2) from iris where month = "March" and Org1 = "ABC" LIMIT 1 group by Manager) from iris where month1 = "April" and Org1 = "ABC"
group by manager
order by manager;
```

Have a look: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

It may probably work. Also, I see that you have repeating subquery. Probably, it is worth to reorganize your query as stored procedure of MySQL, so you may keep value of `Sum(category2)` in a variable. It'll be faster to execute. Check this:

https://www.sqlshack.com/learn-mysql-the-basics-of-mysql-stored-procedures/
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you are looking for

```
Select Manager, 
  Sum(case when month1 = "Avril" then category1 else 0 end) cat1_avr,
  Sum(case when month1 = "March" then category2 else 0 end) cat2_mar,
  Sum(case when month1 = "Avril" then category1 else 0 end) 
  - Sum(case when month1 = "March" then category2 else 0 end) diff
from iris 
where 
  (month1 = "April" or month1 = "March")
and Org1 = "ABC"
group by manager
order by manager;
```