# How to write spring JPA Query from map(key, value) when there is a duplicated value

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa, jpql

I want to get event id's for events with property `messageUUID` equal to passed value from function.
`metaProperties` is a hashmap with keys:

```
"messageId"
"messageType"
"messageUUID"
```

and many events will have the same `messageId` as `messageUUID` values, and when I try to Query for events where key is `messageUUID` and value of it is equal to the one I'm searching for - it gives error

```
  @Query("select event.id from EventLogDb event where (key(event.metaProperties) = 'messageUUID' and :message in VALUE(event.metaProperties))")
  Slice<EventLogDb> findAllByMessage(
          String message, Pageable pageable);

ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

So as far as I understand - it's because `:message in VALUE(event.metaProperties)` gives two results - for keys called `messageId` and `messageUUID`, as they have the same values.

How should I correct this Query to get it working properly?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
because as you said there are many rows with the same messageUUID, thus when you use "=" sign query expects exactly 1 value to be returned, and in your case there are 2,3,... values for one entity -> more than row returned (which messageUUID do you really want against given metaPropeties ?)

Try something like this:

```
@Query("select event.id from EventLogDb event where event.metaProperties IN :messageUUID and event.metaProperties in :message")
```

***NOTE*** - IN operator should not be used if you have NULL values

Or check (restructure) DB model

Maybe this can help: [Solution to "subquery returns more than 1 row" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171474/solution-to-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row-error)