# Active Record Grouping in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
record = #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation 
[#<User id: 2, store_id: 3,location: 'xxx'>, 
#<User id: 4, store_id: 3,location:'yyy'>, 
#<User id: 5, store_id: 4,location:'zzz'>, 
#<User id: 6, store_id: 4,location:'aaa'> ]>
```

How to  group location in comma seperated form based on store_id in ruby to get the result as,

The location of store-id(3) should be combained with comma as (yyy,xxx),

then the location of store-id(4) should be combained with comma as (zzz,aaa)

```
#< store_id: 3,location:'yyy,xxx'>
#< store_id: 4,location:'zzz,aaa'>
```

Comment: How exactly you want to group? By `store_id`, by `location` or both? It isn't clear from your question.

Comment: Are you actually asking for a `sort` rather than a `group`? It looks like, from the little info you've given, that you want a sort.

Comment: i need to group by store_id

Comment: I have updated the question , i no need sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Enumerable.group_by you can do it this way:

`User.all.group_by(&:store_id).map{|store_id,records| {store_id: store_id, location: records.map(&:location).join(',')}}`

If you want to do the grouping on database level, using the group method from ActiveRecord, it is required to have a function on the database that takes care of the concatenation, so the solution would depend on the database being used.

For example, in MySQL (see [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field))

`User.group("store_id").select("store_id, GROUP_CONCAT(location SEPARATOR ',') as location")`