# MySQL - Join on comma-separated field

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

I would like to do some new stuff (for me it's new, bc. I'm just a MySQL-beginner) and I did not find a solution for this.

I got these entries in my database:

```
mytable_items
id | title | catids
1 | test | 32,14

mytable_categories
id | title
32 | Test-Category
14 | Another-Category
```

Now I would like to join this stuff: Show all data from mytable_items - also show the assigned categories (their titles)

The result should be:

```
1 | test | Test-Category, Another-Category
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Comment: Start from [**Database Normalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: recommend splitting `catids` into a link table, if they are in one field, you will have to recursively substring and link.. [ not easy or recommended ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT  m.id,group_concat(mc.title)
FROM    mytable_items m
JOIN    mytable_categories mc
ON      FIND_IN_SET(mc.id,m.catids)
group by
    m.id
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8aeb8/4)**

Comment: I'm not sure that SO should be encouraging this kind of solution - especially not for a beginner!

Comment: @MyFault:- You are welcome. Also to inform you that it is not recommended to store the values as comma seperated specially ids in your table. It will create trouble for you in future. Try to learn Normalisation as suggested

Answer (score -1):

You should use different entities for each CatID. Then you can join both tables and use [Group Concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Select * 
from mytable_items a
join mytable_categories b on a.id = b.id
```

This will join the data and show it correctly.