# Multiple answers on one line

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
matters(matterid, mattername, refno)
mattersjuncstaff(junked, matterid, staffid, lead)
staff(staffid, staffname)
```

A matter may have a number of staff associated with it and a number of those staff will be marked as ‘leads’ i.e. they will have a ‘Y’ in the ‘lead’ field.

I wish to show a table that has a list of matters, the matter name and ref no and those staff marked as leads, ideally in a single row. So it would look something like:

```
reference | mattername      | Lead Staff                        |
ABC1      | matter abc & Co | Fred Smith, Jane Doe, Naomi Watts |
```

etc

I am using the code below but this only displays one person with the lead field marked Y.

```
SELECT refno, mattername, matters.matterid, staffname
  FROM matters
 INNER JOIN matterjuncstaff
 USING (matterid)
 Inner join staff
 using (staffid)
 Inner join matterjuncactions
    On matterjuncactions.matterid = matters.matterid
 WHERE lead = 'Y'
 GROUP BY matters.matterid, nickname
```

Can anyone tell me how I can I get round this?

Comment: Line breaks in SQL queries are allowed and generally add to the readability.

Comment: [This one from 'related' questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field?rq=1) (see sidebar on the right), doesn't that help you too?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to concatenate values from a join and represent that as a field in the result set. [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function is suited for such queries:

```
SELECT m.matterid, m.refno, m.mattername, GROUP_CONCAT(s.staffname) AS LeadStaff
FROM matters m
LEFT JOIN matterjuncstaff mjs ON mjs.matterid = m.matterid AND lead = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN staff s ON s.staffid = mjs.staffid
GROUP BY m.matterid, m.refno, m.mattername
```

The join changed to `LEFT` and `lead = 'Y'` moved there, otherwise you will lose `matters` with no lead staffs.
Use `INNER JOIN` if you only want `matters` having some lead staff.
I have removed `matterjuncactions` as you did not give its info.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) function in mysql to concatenate values from a query into a single string.

For example you could select a row for each matter and append a column with all the concatenated lead staff names as follows:

```
SELECT m.refno,
       m.mattername,
       (Select GROUP_CONCAT(distinct staffname SEPARATOR ', ')
                       from mattersjuncstaff js
                       join staff s
                         on s.staffid = js.staffid
                      where js.lead = 'Y'
                        and js.matterid = m.matterid) as LeadStaffMembers
  FROM matters m
```

**Update**

Here is the same example, but with an added column showing staff members that are not the lead.

```
SELECT m.refno,
   m.mattername,
   (Select GROUP_CONCAT(distinct staffname SEPARATOR ', ')
                   from mattersjuncstaff js
                   join staff s
                     on s.staffid = js.staffid
                  where js.lead = 'Y'
                    and js.matterid = m.matterid) as LeadStaffMembers,
   (Select GROUP_CONCAT(distinct staffname SEPARATOR ', ')
                   from mattersjuncstaff js
                   join staff s
                     on s.staffid = js.staffid
                  where js.lead <> 'Y'
                    and js.matterid = m.matterid) as NonLeadStaffMembers
  FROM matters m
```

Comment: [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) does not accept a full `SELECT`. You can just have `DISTINCT` on expressions from the main query.

Comment: @AmirRahimiFarahani thanks, I updated the query so group_concat does not contain the subquery.

Comment: `SEPARATOR` should also go inside `GROUP_CONCAT`.  
Using the sub-query just slows down the query; please see my answer.

Comment: @AmirRahimiFarahani thanks, i updated it so that it works now, but you are right, your solution with the grouping and single query is more efficient.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply which has worked fine. If I also wanted to select the other staff (ie those where lead!='Y') how could i do that so they appeared in the same table?

Comment: just add another column, but change your where query to be where js.lead <> 'Y'. See updated answer.