# sql query to merge a variable number of rows into one row

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables:

```
people
      name      person_id 
        Joe     1 
        Jack    2 

tags   
      tag_id    tag_name 
          1     blue 
          2     green 
          3     black 
          4     red

assignments
      person_id tag_id 
          1     1 
          1     2 
          1     3 
          1     4 
          2     2 
          2     4
```

What I want is the following result:

result

```
  name  tags 
  Joe   blue,green.black,red
  Jack  green,red
```

What is unique here is that the third table requires me to join the names of the tags first and I wan't those concatenated, not the raw ids...

Comment: where is the complicated query?

Comment: @whereisSQL 404 error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Comment: @whereisSQL added third table, thanks for the heads-up

Comment: Can you delete the first half of your question?

Comment: @Strawberry done. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) method in conjunction with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id) FROM people GROUP BY name;
```

For the edited section, try this:

```
SELECT p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name)
    FROM people p
        JOIN assignments a ON p.person_id=a.person_id
        JOIN tags t ON t.tag_id=a.tag_id
    GROUP BY a.person_id;
```

Comment: @J.Doe If you could add another portion to your original question reflecting the new query I could try and help.

Comment: In general, it's good practice to GROUP BY the non-aggregated columns appearing in the SELECT

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.name
, CONCAT_GROUP(t.tag_id SEPARATOR ',')
FROM tag t,  person p
WHERE t. tag_id = p. tag_id
GROUP BY p. name
```

I hope that this could help

Comment: I really wouldn't encourage the use of this archaic join syntax.