# MySQL multiple row in one row

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, join

I have for the example two table (`person` and `skill`).

```
TABLE PERSON 
id,
First_name,
Last_name,
Mail

TABLE SKILL 
id,
Name,
level
id_person
```

Can I in SQL have the result below :

```
id | First_name | Last_name | Mail | concat(SKILL 1 name, SKILL 1 level) | concat(SKILL 2 name, SKILL 2 level) etc..
```

And to complicate the thing a little, i just want some `skill`, not all.

I see this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field) but, i don't want to concat the result (there is a ton of `skill`).

It's possible ?

Thx

---

For further information, i want to select all the post_meta of a custom post in Wordpress. I have first table `post` (with `title`, `date` etc) and table `wp_postmeta` (with one line per `meta`)
 So, I need a request to select in one row the information of the `post` and the meta : `ID, TITLE, LAST_UPDATE, CONCAT (META_key1, META_value1), CONCAT (META_key1, META_value1)`

So I have this two tables:

- wp_posts
- post_id, post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt,  post_content,
  post_title, post_type
- wp_postmeta
- meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value

I try this

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id WHERE post_type = 'user'
```

In result i Have mutliple row. I just want one

Comment: Do person left join skill, with group_concat.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at my question.

I must use the object WP_Query, i hope the code below help other people

```
global $wpdb;
$args = array('post_type' => 'user');
$result_post = new WP_Query($args);

if ( $result_post->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $result_post->have_posts() ) {
        $result_post->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        echo '<li>' . the_meta() . '</li>';
        echo '<li>' . get_post_meta(get_the_id(),"name",true) . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
```