# How do I combine separate records into one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `product` and two columns `id`,`pricing_category`, and I have a query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ppp.`id` AS productid ,ppp.`pricing_category` AS type1
FROM `product` ppp
WHERE ppp.`finish_product_id`=1
```

The result is:

[image]

I want that `type` will appear as `type1,type2,type3` in a single row for one id. How should I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t.productID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.type1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as type1_ind,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.type1 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as type2_ind,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.type1 = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as type3_ind
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.productID
```

This is dynamic for all productID, not just a specific one. To select a specific one, replace the `group by` with your `WHERE` clause.

This will return an indication for each product on every type if he has it(1) or not(0).

So for example for the data:

```
PRODUCTID | Type1
   1          1
   1          2
   1          3
   2          3
```

This will return:

```
PRODUCTID | TYPE1_IND | TYPE2_IND | TYPE3_IND
    1           1            1           1
    2           0            0           1
```

Or to get them all as one column use `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT t.productID,
       GROUP_CONCAT(concat('TYPE',t.type1))
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.productID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` :

```
select id productid,
       group_concat(concat('type', pricing_category) order by pricing_category) type
from product
where finish_product_id = 1
group by id;
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ee06/1)