# ResultSet manipulation

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

```
mysql> SELECT mi.foodName, mi.price, mi.calories, mi.specialComments, 
ind.ingredient FROM FoodTruck ft LEFT JOIN 
Menu mi ON mi.truckID = ft.truckID LEFT JOIN Ingredients ind ON 
ind.menuID = mi.menuID;
+----------------------+-------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| foodName             | price | calories | specialComments | ingredient      |
+----------------------+-------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
| NULL                 |  NULL |     NULL | NULL            | NULL            |
| NULL                 |  NULL |     NULL | NULL            | NULL            |
| dustins dark rum     |   3.5 |      285 | yummy           | dark rum        |
| dustins dark rum     |   3.5 |      285 | yummy           | ice             |
| rad rachels rumchata |     3 |      375 | dairy free      | rumchata        |
| rad rachels rumchata |     3 |      375 | dairy free      | almond milk     |
| rad rachels rumchata |     3 |      375 | dairy free      | chocolate syrup |
| rad rachels rumchata |     3 |      375 | dairy free      | ice             |
| NULL                 |  NULL |     NULL | NULL            | NULL            |
| NULL                 |  NULL |     NULL | NULL            | NULL            |
+----------------------+-------+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

So, here is mySql query and the result, which via a PreparedStatement, is held in a ResultSet. How, exactly do I get the info out? I know I can have: `while(rs.next()) { int x = resultSet.getInt(); String y = resultSet.getString();}`

but is there a way to NOT repeat the foodName, price, calories and specialComments when dealing with the resultSet? I just need that for `dustins dark rum` and `rad rachels rumchata` and then every ingredient. Basically, as you can see from my query, this is joined from two different tables based on info from a third. So... it is kind of complicated. Not sure how to proceed or if my sql query can be fine tuned... Thank you!!

Comment: What do you mean not repeat? Do you want a solution that won't call `resultSet.getString("foodName")` on every iteration?

Comment: I just meant, when I called `resultSet.getString("foodName")` does resultSet make me do that twice because dustins dark rum is listed twice? Or is there a way for me to just pull each of those things only once but get every ingredient... Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it in 1 query. You can either execute 2 queries (one for the Menu and the second for the Ingredients.).

Your other option is to use something like the GROUP_CONCAT function in conjunction with a GROUP BY clause. See [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)