# Get mysql result of multiple rows in one with group_concat

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has a column `id` and a column `isadmin`.

I want to execute this query, which works just fine:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE isadmin = TRUE;
```

But instead of getting multiple rows I would like to get one row in csv format.
I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field) and created the following query, which does not work, I get a MySQL error:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPERATOR ',') FROM mytable WHERE isadmin = TRUE;
```

The error message is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SEPERATOR ', ') FROM mytable WHERE isadmin = TRUE' at line 1

If this is not enough information just tell me and I will provide them.

Comment: show the exacet error  ..please

Comment: To a rough approximation, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT need form any part of the answer - especially where application code, like PHP, is involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma is the defaul separator so you don't need

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ) FROM mytable WHERE isadmin = TRUE;
```

anyway is separator and nt seperator

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',') FROM mytable WHERE isadmin = TRUE;
```

Comment: I read that about 50 times, still did not get it. This works well, thank you a lot :)