# sql query in many to many relation returns single record

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, many-to-many

How can I get project_id, which has technology_id = 1 and technology_id = 2 in one row?

```
+------------+---------------+
| project_id | technology_id |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |             1 |
|          1 |             2 |
|          3 |             2 |
|          7 |             1 |
|          9 |             1 |
+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: please give an example of your desired result

Comment: Can you post the query that you have tried?

Comment: @Matt project_id 1, and i need count result for pagination

Comment: @Matt thank you very much, you are my master! :D

Comment: Hmmm I think you may have meant someone else or the comment I deleted happened to be what you where looking for.  So to add it back in case someone else stumbles on the message, I had mentions GROUP_CONCAT as a way of concatenating the rows to a single column.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field

Comment: group by 'all' rescued me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the `product_id` and take only those groups having both `technology_id`s

```
select project_id
from your_table
where technology_id in (1,2)
group by project_id
having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: A shot in the dark. Good luck.

Comment: For me this question is totally obvious

Comment: @juergend - but it's not, if the table has two rows with 'project_id' value 1 and 'technology_id ' value 1 it will get selected by your query

Comment: @jhondoe500 using this answer's query, just change `having count(*) = 2` to `having count(distinct technology_id) = 2`

Comment: @Uueerdo nope, if it will be many results, it returns many rows :/

Comment: @jhondoe500 Nope. Besides, the implication is that  `(project_id,technology_id)` forms a compound PK, so the argument is irrelevant. If it isn't a PK, then this isn't really a table in a proper RDBMS sense. And, *if* something else *is* the PK, then `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` will work just fine.

Comment: @jhondoe500 your query will never have a project_id more than once in the results; my alteration just makes sure it doesn't include projects with two references to tech 1 xor 2 and none to 2 xor 1.