# Concatenate Last column Query Result if id match

Tags: mysql

I am getting this result by using select query.

[image]

But what actually i want the result is for example:

```
| 23407 | 42 M-65 Giant jacket, Brandit | Size:L - colour:Olive   |
| 23417 | 42 M-65 Giant jacket, Brandit | Size:2XL - colour:Olive |
| 23413 | 42 M-65 Giant jacket, Brandit | Size:XL - colour:Black  |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Comment: Yes, but I'd handle this kind of thing in application code

Comment: Please refer following link to achieve your result [Concatenate many rows into a single text string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` of that `att_name` column `group by` the `id_product` column like

```
select *, GROUP_CONCAT(att_name) as att_name
from 
  ( 
      // your posted query as subquery 
  ) xxx
group by id_product
```

Comment: thank you so much rahul this is what i am looking for - thanks again buddy

Comment: @Arsalan, consider accepting the answer then by clicking the check button

Comment: rahul would you clear one thing that what is 'xxx' for ?

Comment: @Arsalan, that's the alias for inline subquery else it would result in syntax error

Comment: what i want now is for example:  "product_attribute_id | id_product | name - att_name"

Comment: @Arsalan, Ok but post a separate question for that.

Comment: why separate rahul?