# How to combine rows into one with same column value in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table like this:

```
id  value  
1   a   
1   b   
2   c   
2   d   
2   e
```

I want to combine rows with the same ids into one,here is what i want as result:

```
id  value  
1   a b 
2   c d e
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
select id,group_concat(value) as value from tb_name group by id;
```

if you want space instead ',' then try below query

```
select id,replace(group_concat(value), ',' ,' ') as value from tb_name group by id;
```