# SQL result to multidimensional array (SQL to markdown file)

Tags: php, sql, multidimensional-array, markdown

I am trying to transfer data from a MySQL database (with relational columns) to a markdown file (Pico CMS). For that I created the following SQL query to get the data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
rqypj_mt_links.link_name,
rqypj_mt_links.link_desc,
rqypj_mt_links.address,
rqypj_mt_links.city,
rqypj_mt_links.state,
rqypj_mt_links.country,
rqypj_mt_links.postcode,
rqypj_mt_links.telephone,
rqypj_mt_links.fax,
rqypj_mt_links.email,
rqypj_mt_links.website,
rqypj_mt_links.price,
rqypj_mt_links.lat,
rqypj_mt_links.lng,
rqypj_mt_links.zoom,
rqypj_mt_cats.cat_name,
rqypj_mt_images.filename,
rqypj_mt_cfvalues.value,
rqypj_mt_customfields.caption
FROM rqypj_mt_links
LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_cl
ON rqypj_mt_links.link_id = rqypj_mt_cl.link_id
LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_cats
ON rqypj_mt_cl.cat_id = rqypj_mt_cats.cat_id
LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_images
ON rqypj_mt_links.link_id = rqypj_mt_images.link_id
LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_cfvalues
ON rqypj_mt_links.link_id = rqypj_mt_cfvalues.link_id
LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_customfields
ON rqypj_mt_cfvalues.link_id = rqypj_mt_customfields.cf_id
ORDER BY rqypj_mt_links.link_id, rqypj_mt_cl.cat_id
LIMIT 100
```

This qives the following result

Title | desc | adress | cats | etc.

But when a title has multiple cats I get multiple rows with the same data only the cat row difference. Therefore I am looking for the best way to transfer the SQL data in to a PHP array. F.e.:

```
$result['title']
$result['desc']
$result['cats'][0]
$result['cats'][1]
Etc.
```

I guess that way it w'll be more easy to write the markdown file. Hopefully someone can get me some advise about the best approach and some PHP tips/scripts.

Thanks in advance!
Jelte

Comment: "I guess that way it w'll be more easy to write the markdown file." Maybe, maybe not. What format does the Markdown file need to have?

Comment: I understand but the database contains al the info (40000 rows). So I need to migrate. The markdown file is build up with one item per row. Title | desc | cat 1 | cat 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field) and similarly you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9abbc/7). Maybe it will help you :-)

**Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE link
(
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE cat
(
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE has_cat
(
  `link_id` INT,
  `cat_id` INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (link_id) REFERENCES link(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (cat_id) REFERENCES cat(id)
);
```

**Values**:

```
INSERT INTO link (`name`)
VALUES
    ('John'),
    ('Calvin')
;

INSERT INTO cat (`name`)
VALUES
    ('Garfield'),
    ('Nermal'),
    ('Hobbes')
;

INSERT INTO has_cat (link_id, cat_id)
VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (2, 3)
;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT link.name AS link, GROUP_CONCAT(cat.name) AS cats
FROM link, has_cat, cat
WHERE
  link.id = has_cat.link_id AND
  cat.id = has_cat.cat_id
GROUP BY link.name
```

**Result**:

```
|   link |            cats |
|--------|-----------------|
| Calvin |          Hobbes |
|   John | Garfield,Nermal |
```

### Make a PHP array from it

From here, you can [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the comma separated string into an array:

```
var_dump( explode( ',', $result['cats'] ) );
```

That will give you:

```
array(2)
(
    [0] => string(8) "Garfield"
    [1] => string(6) "Nermal"
)
```